# CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page

Tags: css, footer

I have the following page (deadlink: `http://www.workingstorage.com/Sample.htm` ) that has a footer which I can't make sit at the bottom of the page.

I want the footer to

- stick to the window bottom when the page is short and the screen is not filled, and
- stay at the document end and move down as normal when there is more than a screenful of content (instead of overlapping the content).

The CSS is inherited and befuddles me. I can't seem to change it properly to put a minimum height on the content or make the footer go to the bottom.

Comment: It's amazing that this is such a common problem. Maybe in CSS4 we'll see implementations of "make a nav bar" and "make a footer" since these are so frequently attempted.

Comment: There will never be CSS4 (CSS3 will just grow). I'm thinking this will be fixed with the implementation of `flexbox`.

Comment: Excellent article on this: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: http://expertsuggestion.com/css-snippets/8

Answer (score 379, accepted):

A simple method is to make the body `100%` of your page, with a `min-height` of `100%` too. This works fine if the height of your footer does not change.

Give the footer a negative margin-top:

```
footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you know the height of your footer ahead of time. Sometimes footers have dynamic content, or your building a framework. Any ideas for variable height footers?

Comment: @Costa check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25218797/607874), for a solution that works with variable height footers.

Comment: for dynamic content just omit the "height" and the footer will adapt to content. *Not tested in all browser*

Comment: This may require `box-sizing: border-box;` to the body [and the `#container`].

Comment: This seems like a lot of weird tricks, there are answers below which are simple and use no tricks.

Comment: The `min-height` on `body` is usually enough for me, though setting the value to `100vh` (since about 2013) feels like a better value than `100%` even though they should be the same on the `body`. Or you can set the `min-height` on the `main` so that the footer is off-screen.

Comment: It doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/fku3nraz/

Answer (score 560):

## Below are 4 different methods of mine:

In each example the texts are freely-editable to illustrate how the content would render in different scenarios.

---

### 1) Flexbox

```css
body{ min-height: 100vh; margin:0; }

header{ min-height:50px; background:lightcyan; }
footer{ min-height:50px; background:PapayaWhip; }

/* The article fills all the space between header & footer */
body{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; }
article{ flex:1; }
```

```html
<body>
  <header contentEditable>Header</header>
  <article contentEditable>Content</article>
  <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

---

### 2) Grid

```css
body{ 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

header{ 
  min-height:50px;
  background:lightcyan; 
}

footer{ 
  min-height:50px; 
  background:PapayaWhip; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header contentEditable>Header</header>
  <article contentEditable>Content</article>
  <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

---

This method below uses a "trick" by placing an `::after` pseudo-element on the `body`, and set it to have the *exact* height of the footer, so it will occupy the exact same space the footer does, so when the footer is `absolute` positioned over it, it would appear like the footer is really taking up space and eliminate the negative affects of it's absolute positioning (for example, going over the body's content)

### 3) `position:absolute` (no *dynamic* footer height)

```css
body{ min-height:100vh; margin:0; position:relative; }
header{ min-height:50px; background:lightcyan; }
footer{ background:PapayaWhip; }

/* Trick: */
body {
  position: relative;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px; /* Set same as footer's height */
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header contentEditable>Header</header>
  <article contentEditable>Content</article>
  <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

---

### 4) Table-layout

```css
html{ height:100%; }
body { min-height:100%;  margin:0; }

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightcyan;
}

article { 
  height: 1%;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: PapayaWhip;
}

/**** Trick: ****/

body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; 
}

body > footer {
   display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header contentEditable>Header</header>
  <article contentEditable>Content</article>
  <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Simple and elegant and more importantly it works. Other solutions fail when you start adding divs with `display: table` `display: table-row` `display:table-cell`. However I found I needed to add `body {margin-top: 0; padding-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;}` to avoid a scroll bar. You could cater for this by adjusting the `body:after height` but I am specifying mine in rem not px so it becomes problematical.

Comment: @SteveWaring - Thank you. Updated this answer since it was quite old. Now I'm in favor of using `flexbox`

Comment: The CSS under "basic common markup" had a small error which caused it to not work (the error was not present in the linked "DEMO", which is ok). I took the liberty of fixing it.

Comment: THANK YOU! The flexbox solution is actually simple and uses no hacks or weird fixed sizes or fixed positions.

Comment: Seems like the dynamic solutions don't work well when body has scrollbar. When you scroll, the footer floats instead of being kept at bottom.

Comment: Used the flexbox solution but on long pages the body did not grow with the content, so I changed `body: { height: 100% }` to `body: { min-height: 100% }`.

Comment: These colors look delicious.

Comment: For angular issue with encapsulation and use of ng-content, none of the solution works but the one using grid (#2). Thx for posting so many variants

Comment: Another tip would be instead of using `height:100vh` try to use `min-height:100vh` there are some cases where contents are far too big on viewport, would instead set it as a minimum height.

Comment: None of these worked in my design, except grid, which also introduced new issues. Grid was the closest, but created horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: making the container (body in my case) ```relative``` (3) - simple great solution

Comment: wow - i love the flexbox solution, never would have come up with this margin-top: auto on my own. works like a charm, thanks a ton! Had to change the height of the body to "min-height: 100vh", though, just like @WesleyBrianLachenal . Besides of that - perfect solution even for responsive layouts with variable height of footer.

Comment: @WesleyBrianLachenal I fixed the flexbox example to `min-height` now also (the others were already fixed from what I could see), don't know if we have to wait for it to be reviewed by someone or if my score is godlike so I can just change :P

Comment: The grid solution worked perfectly. However some content overflow issues can arise if an explicit width is not set on the main content column; by default, this is `auto`, and allows content to expand the width of a container.

Setting to `grid-template-columns: minmax(0,1fr)` helps solve this issue.

Reference: ["Preventing a Grid Blowout" on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/)

Answer (score 85):

A very simple flex solution that does not assume fixed heights or changing position of elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

---

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

footer {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
}

main {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm! even for res more than 4k footer sticks at the bottom

Comment: major browsers ⊅ IE11

Comment: Worked! Can you please explain how does it work?

Comment: Why it doesn't work in IE 11, if it supports flexbox?

Comment: I was trying to play with position but this solution is I think better. thanks

Answer (score 76):

A very simple approach which works great cross browser is this:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">header</div>
   <div id="body">body</div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That approach doesn't work on Firefox on Android, if you resize the window with two fingers

Comment: Yeah I don't like this approach.  It's not very responsive, because if you have a device with a smaller height (e.g. a mobile device) and the content will naturally overflow the viewer height, the footer will overlay on your content because of its absolute positioning. I think the flexbox approach is better.

Answer (score 64):

I've used this to stick my footer to the bottom and it worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="allButFooter">
        <!-- Your page's content goes here, including header, nav, aside, everything -->
    </div>
    <footer>
        <!-- Footer content -->
    </footer>
</body>
```

That's the only modification you have to do in the HTML, add that `div` with the `"allButFooter"` class. I did it with all the pages, those that were so short, I knew the footer wouldn't stick to the bottom, and also pages long enough that I already knew I had to scroll. I did this, so I could see that it works ok in the case that a page's content is dynamic.

**CSS**

```
.allButFooter {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

The `"allButFooter"` class has a `min-height` value that depends on the viewport's height (`100vh` means 100% of the viewport height) and the footer's height, that I already knew was `40px`.

That's all I did, and it worked perfectly for me. I haven't tried it in every browser, just Firefox, Chrome and Edge, and the results were as I wanted. The footer sticks to the bottom, and you don't have to mess with z-index, position, or any other properties. The position of every element in my document was the default position, I didn't change it to absolute or fixed or anything.

***Working with responsive design***

Here's something I would like to clear out. This solution, with the same Footer that was 40px high didn't work as I expected when I was working in a responsive design using `Twitter-Bootstrap`. I had to modify the value I was substracting in the function:

```
.allButFooter {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 95px); 
}
```

This is probably because `Twitter-Bootstrap` comes with its own margins and paddings, so that's why I had to adjust that value.

Comment: I have hit problems with all sorts of solutions to this problem. This solution works with my page that varies what is displayed in the body using `display: none` Thanks. It's nice and simple too.

Comment: after many hours of trying solutions only two worked nl. ```position: fixed; bottom: 0``` and this one.  This solution is the best because the footer does not stick to the bottom, but stays at the end of the scrollable page.

Comment: to build on your answer, you can look at it another way by setting the ```.footer {max-height: calc(100vh+40px); position: absolute}```.  As it also works, you should just know your body size.

Comment: `min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);` with Bulma, here. Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

From IE7 onwards you can simply use

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed) for support.

Comment: I don't want the footer at the bottom when there is content beyond the footer. I want the footer to stick to the bottom when there isn't enough, and then expand downward as normal when there is more than a screenful. The sticky footer solved this.

Comment: @Caveatrob: I took the liberty of editing this important information into your question, just to avoid misunderstandings (for future readers, you have presumably solved this in the meantime :-) ).

Comment: This solution is the only one printing the footer to every page and it is so simple! But i cant get it working that the content is not overlapping with the main content. Anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 35):

#### Keep the footer at the bottom by using Flexbox

```html
<div style="min-height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; 
            justify-content:space-between;">
 
     <div> <!-- Wrapper (Without footer) -->
   
        <header>
         I am a header.
        </header>
  
        <article>
        I am an article!
        </article>
   
    </div> <!-- End: Wrapper (Without footer) -->
 
 
     <footer>
     I am a footer.
     </footer>
 
</div>
```

##### Note

- Make sure that you are wrapping everything in a `<div>` or any other block-level element with the following CSS styles: `min-height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:space-between;` .
- Make sure that you are wrapping everything but the footer element in a `<div>` or any other block-level element.
- Make sure that you using `<footer>` or any other block-level element to wrap the footer.

##### Code Explanation

- `min-height: 100vh` ensures that the body element will stretch to at least the full height of the screen
- `flex-direction: column` keeps the behavior of normal document flow in terms of retaining stacked block elements (which assumes direct children of the body are all indeed block elements).
- `justify-content:space-between` pushes the footer to the bottom of the screen.

---

Check out how to do the same (Keeping the footer at the bottom) by using Bootstrap 5 - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap/68836851#68836851)

Comment: Simplest but yet amazing, works just fine!

Answer (score 18):

**A simple solution that i use, works from IE8+**

Give min-height:100% on html so that if content is less then still page takes full view-port height and footer sticks at bottom of page. When content increases the footer shifts down with content and keep sticking to bottom.

JS fiddle working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3L3h64qo/2/

### Css

```
html{
  position:relative; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
/*Normalize html and body elements,this style is just good to have*/
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.pageContentWrapper{
  margin-bottom:100px;/* Height of footer*/
} 
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

### Html

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <div class="pageContentWrapper">
            <!-- All the page content goes here-->
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it good..but just Update

 .pageContentWrapper{
  padding-bottom:100px;/* Height of footer*/
}

Comment: I don’t want to make an unnecessary scroll bar when possible.

Answer (score 16):

Yet, another really simple solution is this one:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
}

footer {
    background-color: grey;
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfSM3/551/)**

The trick is to use a `display:table` for the whole document and `display:table-row` with `height:0` for the footer.

Since the footer is the only body child that has a display as `table-row`, it is rendered at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I love css tables, but they create issue down the line that are pretty strange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898115/how-to-hide-and-show-a-table-row-css-tables

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be completely working - Firefox ignores footer height 0. I used height 1px or even 1% instead. Edge, IE11, Chrome and mobile safari are happy with 0.

Comment: I really love this solution. But when i build my layout like this the browser calculation of child elements are wiered. Let's say we want to have a container at the top of the page and it have to be `height: 100%` then actually its 100% when the viewport ratio is 1/1 (square). When the viewport gets wider (landscape) height will be more then 100% and if narrower (portrait) less then 100%. So the height is proportinoal to the width of the window. Tried to solve it with another wrapper but this didn't work. Somebody got a solution or at lest a hint???

Comment: @Axel In this [version](http://jsfiddle.net/vfSM3/810/) I've added a blue div on top with 100% height that occupies all the height (minus the footer height), regardless of viewport width. I think you might have other CSS messing things up. Try to create a minimized version of your issue based on my original jsFiddle

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos [Thank you so much for your response. It seems to be a FireFox Bug. See screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xTVBNjJFKReU1fS29jdktzb3M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Axel It might depend on your specific markup, but that can be fixed for all browsers, if you add `display: table-row;` to the div [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfSM3/811/)

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Thx again for response. I mocked up some real life markup to illustrate my needs. See [working fiddle without sticky footer](http://jsfiddle.net/Elstermann/mfoozdLo/2/) and [not working fiddle with sticky footer](http://jsfiddle.net/Elstermann/njr7gtbq/1/). One could say: "if you have a full viewport height element in your page - you don't need a sticky footer anymore!" which is right.
But its about making a boilerplate template for cms puposes - so the actual content is unknown. Any help would be very appreciated (thx for your time).

Answer (score 16):

Do this

```
<footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;"> </footer>
```

You can also read about flex it is supported by all modern browsers

**Update**: I read about flex and tried it. It worked for me. Hope it does the same for you. Here is how I implemented.Here main is not the ID it is the  div

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Here you can read more about flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Do keep in mind it is not supported by older versions of IE.

Comment: This is the best answer in practice. Using `flex-grow: 1` for something above the footer will keep the footer at the bottom properly.

Comment: First answer that I found that actually works and doesn't need random `div`s. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This is known as a sticky footer. A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sticky+footer) for it comes up with a lot of results. [A CSS Sticky Footer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090210170534/http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is the one I've used successfully. But there are more.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Source for this code](https://web.archive.org/web/20090210170449/http://ryanfait.com:80/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Answer (score 8):

One thing to be wary of is mobile devices, since they implement the idea of the viewport in an 'unusual' way:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW25

As such, using `position: fixed;` (as I've seen recommended in other places) usually isn't the way to go. Of course, it depends upon the exact behaviour you're after.

What I've used, and has worked well on desktop and mobile, is:

```
<body>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

with

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
 
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
footer {
  margin-top:calc(5% + 60px);
}
```

This works fine

Comment: good for a small enough screen. but make the screen larger and see what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/cn13adr5/1/

Answer (score 7):

Works for me.

```
#container{ 
  height:100vh; 
  margin:0; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
}

#footer{
  margin-top:auto; 
}


<div id="container">
   <div id="header">header</div>
   <div id="body">body</div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container{ 
  height:100vh; 
  margin:0; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
}

#footer{
  margin-top:auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">header</div>
   <div id="body">body</div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I just answered as similar question in here:

[Position footer at bottom of page having fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header)

I'm pretty new at web development, and I know this has been answered already, but this is the easiest way I found to solve it and I  think is somehow different. I wanted something flexible because the footer of my web app has a dynamic height, I ended up using FlexBox and a spacer.

1. Start by setting the height for your html and body

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I'm assuming a `column` behavior for our app, in the case you need to add a header, hero or any content vertically aligned.

2. Create the spacer class

```css
.spacer {
    flex: 1; 
}
```

3. So later on your HTML could be something like

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header> Header </header>
    Some content...
    <div class='spacer'></div>
    <footer> Footer </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can play with it here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmGZQL

Answer (score 4):

My jQuery method, this one puts the footer at the bottom of the page if the page content is less than the window height, or just puts the footer after the content otherwise:

Also, keeping the code in it's own enclosure before other code will reduce the time it takes to reposition the footer.

```
(function() {
    $('.footer').css('position', $(document).height() > $(window).height() ? "inherit" : "fixed");
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

I achieved that using CSS grid, basically I defined 3 rows:

- Header
- content
- footer

And the used grid to define the sizes, the trick is to align the footer at the end of the row, like this:

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

footer {
    display: grid;
    align-self: end; /* The trick */
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    Header content
  </header>
  
  <h1>main body</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  
  <footer>
    <p>Hello there.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use more rows but remember to add the to the CSS, or wrap everything inside a div.

This guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-align-self) really helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `position: absolute;` this is important, then `bottom:0`

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have myself been looking into this problem. I have seen quite a few solutions and each of them had issues, often involving some magic numbers.

So using best practices from various sources I came up with this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfSM3/248/

The thing I wanted to achieve specifically here was to get the main content to scroll between footer and header inside green area.

Here is a simple CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    height: 4em;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    bottom: 5em;
    overflow: auto;
}
.contentinner {
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: -4em 0 -2em 0;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
footer {
     height: 2em;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I hate sites designed like this. Why do you want to restrict the amount of text I can read at the same time? I don't need to see the header and footer all the time, I know where to find them when I want them.

Comment: @Tarmil have a look at http://www.numerics.info. Do you see now when this could be useful?

Answer (score 3):

What I did

Html

```
    <div>
      <div class="register">
         /* your content*/    
      </div>
      <div class="footer" />
  <div/>
```

CSS

```
.register {
          min-height : calc(100vh - 10rem);
  }

.footer {
         height: 10rem;
 }
```

Don't need to use position **fixed** and **absolute**. Just write the html in proper way.

Comment: This is the best solution. I'm using it. The main answers don't work as good as this simple solution using vh and calc.

Comment: The best solution. It's accurate and the proper solution that we can implement.

Answer (score 3):

## ONE line solution using Bootstrap

Apart from all the CSS and jQuery solutions provided,
I have listed a solution using **Bootstrap** with a single class declaration on ***body*** tag: `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between`

- This *DOES NOT* require ***knowing the height*** of the footer ahead of time.
- This *DOES NOT* require setting ***position absolute***.
- This **WORKS** with dynamic divs that ***overflow*** on smaller screens.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between text-white text-center">

        <header class="p-5 bg-dark">
          <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>
        <main class="p-5 bg-primary">
          <h1>Main</h1>
        </main>
        <footer class="p-5 bg-warning">
          <h1>Footer</h1>
        </footer>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice approach, though you might want to add min-height: 100vh; to the body so it fills the entire viewport

Answer (score 3):

I consider you can set the main content to viewport height, so if the content exceeds, the height of the main content will define the position of the footer

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

main {
  background: blue;
  /* This is the most important part*/
  height: 100vh; 
  
}
footer{
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: I hit problem when the content in main has bigger high than main. In my case I have many articles in the main as grid. So when the articles count is 50 for example I have very bigger vertical scroll and content in the main has very big high. In this situation the footer appeared somewhere behind my grid. 


FIX: I set ONLY min-height:100vh instead of height:100vh in the main and working perfectly in every case.

P.S. Im using material-ui in reactjs but it does not matter I think

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Position `fixed` with `bottom`, `left`, and `right` set to 0 works best for me:

```
.footer {    
    position: fixed;
    background : #d1ccc0;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 0;
    right : 0;
    height : 50px;
}
```

Position `absolute` doesn't stick to the bottom, but `fixed` does.

Comment: You do realize that puts the footer over the content of the page...?

Comment: @DavidMartins Then use css grids

Answer (score 1):

In comparisson to other solutions, one does not need to add extra containers. Therefor this solution is a bit more elegant. Beneath the code example I'll explain why this works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
        
            html
            {
                height:100%;
            }
            
            body
            {
                min-height:100%;
                padding:0; /*not needed, but otherwise header and footer tags have padding and margin*/
                margin:0; /*see above comment*/
            }
        
            body
            {
                position:relative;
                padding-bottom:60px; /* Same height as the footer. */           
            }
            
            footer
            {
                position:absolute;
                bottom:0px;
                height: 60px;
                
                background-color: red;
            }
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>header</header>
        
        
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the first thing we do, is make the biggest container( html ) 100%. The html page is as big as the page itself. Next we set the body height, it can be bigger than the 100% of the html tag, but it should at least be as big, therefore we use min-height 100%.

We also make the body relative. Relative means you can move the block element around relative from its original position. We don't use that here though. Because relative has a second use. Any absolute element is either absolute to the root (html) or to the first relative parent/grandparent. That's what we want, we want the footer to be absolute, relative to the body, namely the bottom.

The last step is to set the footer to absolute and bottom:0, which moves it to the bottom of the first parent/grandparent that is relative ( body ofcourse ).

Now we still have one problem to fix, when we fill the complete page, the content goes beneath the footer. Why? Well, because the footer is no longer inside the "html flow", because it is absolute. So how do we fix this? We will add padding-bottom to the body. This makes sure the body is actually bigger than it's content.

Answer (score 1):

Just customize the footer section

```
.footer 
{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 1rem;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```
 <div class="footer">
   Footer is always bootom
 </div>
```

Comment: Not working. It always stick to bottom even if we have very big page. It cannot scroll with all page but just stick to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
 </head>

<body>
 <div id="page-container">
   <div id="content-wrap">
     <!-- all other page content -->
   </div>
   <footer id="footer"></footer>
 </div>
</body>

</html>


#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple. This solution doesn't require to know footer height.

```html
<body>
  <div class="app">
    Website
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
.app {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I found many similar answers, the only solution that I could find where the footer was always at the bottom *and* did not display over the existing data was the following:

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/cn13adr5/2/ with a large enough screen. Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
    margin-top:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the html, body, and the other rows except the footer to 100%.
e.g

```
<body>
<header></header>
<content></content>
<footer></footer>
```

the CSS becomes

```
html, body, header, content{
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions didn't work for me but the best option I found was the example below when I decided to use the flex option.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;   
}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-contents{ 
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -77px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.footer{
    height:  77px;
    min-height: 77px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    
    
}

.footer-text{
  color: #FFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    #content{
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .footer{
        position: relative;
        /*position: absolute;*/
        height: 77px;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="main-contents" >
      this is the main content
    </div>
  </body>

  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="footer-text">This is the sticky footer</p>
  </footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **fixed height** footers, you can also use **css variables** to do it.

```css
/* Globals */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--navbar-height) - var(--footer-height));
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: cyan;
}


/* Navbar */

:root {
  --navbar-height: 60px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(75deg, yellow, orange);
}


/* Footer */

:root {
  --footer-height: 40px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--footer-height);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, yellow 0%, orange 25%, teal 25%, cyan 50%, red 50%, magenta 75%, black 75%, grey 100%);
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, black 0%, cyan 100%); */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">Navbar</nav>
  <main>Main Section</main>
  <footer>&copy; Test 2021 - FOREVER ❤♾</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
 </head>

<body>
   <header class='header'></header>
   <div class="body-content">
     <!-- all other page content -->
   </div>
   <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>

html,
body{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  display:flex,
  flex-direction: column,
}

.body-content {
  flex-grow:1   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <!--Some Content-->
    </div>

    <section class="footer"></section>
</body>

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    top: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have used in my many projects and never got any single issue :)

For your reference, Code are in snippet

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
  background:green;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

.footer{
  background:gold;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    Content Area
    </div>
  
  <div class="push">
    </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    Footer Area
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

### Dynamic one liner using jQuery

All CSS methods I have come across are too rigid. Also, setting the footer to `fixed` is not an option if that's not part of the design.

---

Tested on:

- Chrome: 60
- FF: 54
- IE: 11

Assuming this layout:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Use the following jQuery function:

```
$('#content').css("min-height", $(window).height() - $("#footer").height() + "px");
```

What that does is set the `min-height` for `#content` to the **window height** - **the height of the footer** what ever that might be at the time.

Since we used `min-height`, if `#content` height exceeds the **window height**, the function degrades gracefully and does not any effect anything since it's not needed.

See it in action:

```js
$("#fix").click(function() {
  $('#content').css("min-height", $(window).height() - $("#footer").height() + "px");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #111;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #444
}

#content {
  background: #999;
}

#footer {
  background: #777;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Very short content</p>
    <button id="fix">Fix it!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Mr. Footer</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Same snippet on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84nLyn6z/)

---

### Bonus:

We can take this further and make this function adapt to dynamic viewer height resizing like so:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content').css("min-height", $(window).height() - $("#footer").height() + "px");
  }).resize();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #111;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #444
}

#content {
  background: #999;
}

#footer {
  background: #777;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Very short content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Mr. Footer</div>
</body>

</html>
```