# css layout with minimal height 100% and varial-width sections

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a layout in which total minimal height would be 100% (if site would be longer, the footer should go down along with it). Header and footer should have 100% width.

http://jsfiddle.net/MXrY2/2/

This is what I came up with (a bit changed example from cssgirl.com), I only need this page to be 100% height at start (and go down if there's more content).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height#689290) applies here. Specifically, see the steps [outlined here](http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/).

Comment: Well, thank you. After playing a while with this solution I finally managed to do what I wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/dGBPf/

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 divs header content footer
set the min-height of content div to be 100% so thats its height is always 100% long if content is longer

Comment: This will push the footer and the lower part of the content off the bottom of the page.

Comment: yes I guess that's how @Marcin wants it to be..
see the question:
_*if site would be longer, the footer should go down along with it*_

Comment: I think the OP wants the entire layout (including footer and header) to, at minimum, be 100% height so there is never a gap under the footer.