# Flushing footer to bottom of the page, twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I am generally familiar with the technique of flushing a footer using css.

But I am having some trouble getting this approach to work for Twitter bootstrap, most likely due to the fact that Twitter bootstrap is responsive in nature. Using Twitter bootstrap I am not able to get the footer to flush to the bottom of the page using the approach described in the above blog post.

Comment: Before test all answers below keep in mind the OP wants to have it working with twitter bootstrap.As it is not a must, twitter bootstrap works with Jquery,what means it is Javascript enabled.For that reason just test my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap/20971428#20971428

Comment: Official example : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/sticky-footer-navbar.css

Comment: Link is broken! Can anyone please fix the official example link?

Comment: @PassionInfinite https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ it may become older version in future because of 4.0 i guess.

Comment: Link to latest version https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: 9 years old. still a huge problem. why is it so complicated to flush a footer to the bottom of a page?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Found the snippets [here](http://bootstrapfooter.codeplex.com/) works really well for bootstrap

Html:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main" class="container clear-top">
    <p>Your content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom:150px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 150px;
  clear:both;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have attempted so far. Accepted this as the answer.

Comment: Hi, I've implement this method, it works great but now I've got some problems with displaying page on iphone (page is zoomed in). Any ideas what is the problem? Here is some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621090/web-page-made-with-twitter-bootstrap-zoomed-in-on-iphone

Comment: Just in case you've read this answer and not scrolled down it's worth looking at the other answers

Comment: especialy this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap/20971428#20971428

Comment: This is best method I have found for Bootstrap. For device responsiveness remember to use media queries to update #main and .footer heights for different screen sizes

Comment: a big problem with this is you are assigning a height to the footer so it is no longer responsive. you need to let the content set the height. and control the change to 100% width for each column at the specific media query with your padding and margin

Comment: How about giving padding-bottom:150px;  to #wrap instead of #main ?

Comment: You could use relative units for the height of the footer if device responsiveness is needed, like em for example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: This is the best answer that does not force sticky footer. Works great with Bootstrap!

Comment: The links are broken nowadays.

Comment: Incase using HAML please use the this code it works like charm `%footer.card.text-center`

Comment: Flexible footer height, vanilla Boostrap, no JS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623350/5459567

Answer (score 518):

This is now included with Bootstrap 2.2.1.

**Bootstrap 3.x**

Use the navbar component and add `.navbar-fixed-bottom` class:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>
```

**Bootstrap 4.x**

```
<div class="navbar fixed-bottom"></div>
```

Don't forget to add `body { padding-bottom: 70px; }` or otherwise the page content may be covered.

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

Comment: @ChuanYeong Unfortunately there is no `navbar-static-bottom`.

Comment: @LawrenceWoodman Uugh just realized that. My mistake. Turns out I've more or less implemented sticky footer before putting in navbar-static-bottom. So I thought the class actually works..holy crap. Oh and, navbar-fixed-bottom isn't really what the OP was asking for anyway

Comment: @MikeCurry he not asked about a fixed footer, but a one that "fills" the empty space, if your page don't have enough content to make the footer stays at bottom. If your footer is only informational, a fixed one is only taking valuable space.

Comment: He says he is not able to flush the footer to the bottom of the page, which is what this technique does.

Comment: This is not sticky footer, because it is used position:fixed; which is not right

Comment: Yep this solution only flushes to the bottom of the viewport not the bottom of the page. i.e. the footer is always visible.

Comment: Had to downvote the answer because it give confusion.The OP not wants a sticky footer.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap `v3.3.1`, and still there is no `navbar-bottom` for **sticky behaviour**. Two `div`s are the way to go (didn't downvote as this answer is still useful).

Comment: This one gives fixed footer so be careful if you don't want sticky footer. Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701056/128028 (accepted answer) for non-sticky footer.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me , however link is not working so check this page - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Comment: Bootstrap 5,     `<footer class="mt-auto text-center fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Text Footer
        </div>
    </footer>`

Answer (score 88):

A working example for Twitter bootstrap **NOT STICKY FOOTER**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;

    if (footerTop < docHeight)
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', 10+ (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
});
</script>
```

Version that always updates in case user opens devtools or resizes window.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var docHeight = $(window).height();
            var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
            var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;
            var marginTop = (docHeight - footerTop + 10);

            if (footerTop < docHeight)
                $('#footer').css('margin-top', marginTop + 'px'); // padding of 30 on footer
            else
                $('#footer').css('margin-top', '0px');
            // console.log("docheight: " + docHeight + "\n" + "footerheight: " + footerHeight + "\n" + "footertop: " + footerTop + "\n" + "new docheight: " + $(window).height() + "\n" + "margintop: " + marginTop);
        }, 250);
    });
</script>
```

### You need at least an element with a `#footer`

When not want the scrollbar if content would fit to screen just change the value of 10 to 0
The scrollbar will show up if content not fits to screen.

Comment: Alternatively, to have the footer stay in place and flush to the bottom, change `margin-top` to `padding-bottom` in the JS.

Comment: Yeah, I went with this one too.  CSS can be so stupid sometimes.  Not that it's impossible, but general purpose solutions can be hard to come by, and fixing annoying things like this in our layouts shouldn't take trips to stack exchange, multiple gist revisions, cross-browswer testing, and eventual surrender to a simple JS trick.  Yeah, I feel a bit dirty, but at least it works.

Comment: every single solution I've looked at is wrong.  This is the ONLY one that actually does what it's supposed to do - stick the footer to the bottom of the page, without obscuring any content if the browser is resized.

Comment: it didnt work quiet as well as expected for me, still, one of the better answers, i fixed my issue by replacing `$('#footer').height();` with `$('#footer').outerHeight();`

Comment: Great answer! I had a couple adaptations that I think improve it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385654/8207

Comment: The best answer I've found. If you want it to work after window resize just put the main code from the answer inside `$(window).resize(function() {//main code goes here});` and invoke `$(window).resize();` to set it when page loads.

Comment: Tried 4 of the solutions on this page and nothing was working for me except this.

Comment: It will not adjust on window resize, so put the code in a function, call it once, then call it on window resize events: $(window).on("resize", etc....

Comment: i dont know why i need to change the 10 to 40. theres a gap

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution in the history of humanity !!!

Comment: Don't forget to remove bootstrap "pt" or "mt" classes applied to your footer if doing this. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 38):

For [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) we use two `DIV's` in the HTML for basic **sticky footer** effect. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    min-height:100%;
}
.footer {
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Comment: He said he's using Twitter Bootstrap. What would be the easiest way of integrating this into Bootstrap without completely rewriting the HTML?

Comment: If OP want's to achieve Sticky Footer effect then he have to change his MarkUp

Comment: Thank you! This has been the only method that has actually worked for me in an ASP.NET MVC5 site that uses Bootstrap. +1

Answer (score 36):

Here's how to implement this from the official page:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

I just tested it right now and it WORKS GREAT! :)

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">

      <!-- Begin page content -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The relevant CSS code is this:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#push,
#footer {
    height: 30px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it was definitely the best solution (not to mention the only one that worked) for my particular project, and of course it's nice that it's directly from the project itself.

Comment: I don't know what the deal was, but I couldn't get it to work without adding a scroll to the pages. I ended up changing the .wrapper CSS so the min-height was "calc(100% - 120px)" where the 120px is the height of my footer and removed the <div id="push"></div> from the html since it didn't seem to be doing anything aside from adding height to the page I didn't need.

Answer (score 31):

Much simpler official example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Use the flex utilities built into Bootstrap 4!
Here's what I've come up with using mostly Bootstrap 4 utilities.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <header></header>
  <div class="container flex-grow-1">
    <div>Some Content</div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

- `.d-flex` to make the main div a flex container
- `.flex-column` on the main div to arrange your flex items in a column
- `min-height: 100vh` to the main div, either with a style attribute or in your CSS, to fill the viewport vertically
- `.flex-grow-1` on the container, element to have the main content container take up all the space that remains in the viewport height.

Comment: Instead of  `min-height: 100vh` the `min-vh-100` class from Bootstrap can be used.

Comment: This solution worked great including the min-vh-100 suggestion from @ikonuk

Comment: I just wanted to say THANK YOU!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!  I've tried it here:
[link](https://car-listing-project-staging.herokuapp.com/user/login)

However, I needed to set the style as the `min-vh-100` class didn't work for me.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 30):

In the [latest version](https://getbootstrap.com/) of bootstrap 4.3, this can be done using `.fixed-bottom` class.

```
<div class="fixed-bottom"></div>
```

Here's how I use it with the footer:

```
<footer class="footer fixed-bottom container">
        <hr>
        <p>&copy; 2017 Company, Inc.</p>
</footer>
```

You can find more information in the *position* documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom).

Comment: This still works with the official 4 version unleashed.

Comment: Note that the example at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer has a line-height=60px style on the footer element. This is not only unnecessary, it also prevents the footer from working properly if it's the parent of one or more div elements, which is commonly the case.

Comment: It makes the footer sticky?!

Answer (score 28):

#### Keep the footer at the bottom by using Bootstrap 5

```html
    <div class="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column 
                justify-content-between">
     
         <div> <!-- Wrapper (Without footer) -->
       
            <header>
             I am a header.
            </header>
      
            <article>
            I am an article!
            </article>
       
        </div> <!-- End: Wrapper (Without footer) -->
     
     
         <footer>
         I am a footer.
         </footer>
     
    </div>
```

---

[**Live Demo in CodePen**](https://codepen.io/rasaf-ibrahim/pen/gOmzPZe?editors=0110)

---

##### Note

- Make sure that you are wrapping everything in a `<div>` or any other block-level element with the following Bootstrap classes: `min-vh-100, d-flex,flex-column,justify-content-between`   .
- Make sure that you are wrapping everything but the footer element in a `<div>` or any other block-level element.
- Make sure that you using `<footer>` or any other block-level element to wrap the footer.

##### Code Explanation

- `min-vh-100` ensures that the body element will stretch to at least the full height of the screen
- `flex-column` keeps the behavior of normal document flow in terms of retaining stacked block elements (which assumes direct children of the body are all indeed block elements).
- `justify-content-between` pushes the footer to the bottom of the screen.

---

Check out how to do the same (Keeping the footer at the bottom) with just CSS - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b/67846892#67846892)

Answer (score 22):

Well I found mix of `navbar-inner` and   `navbar-fixed-bottom`

```
<div id="footer">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inner  navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p class="muted credit"><center>ver 1.0.1</center></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

It seems good and works for me

[image]

See example in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/699/)**</kbd>

Comment: simplest and most elegant solution. Be leery of home brewing your own css code as it will not be backwards compatible with bootstrap

Comment: I used this, and had a problem on an old android (froy maybe?) with pages that were shorter than the screen.  Otherwise it worked well on FF, Chrome, IE11, iPhone, nexus 7.

Comment: Perfect and extremely simple!

Answer (score 15):

[HenryW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971428/8207) is good, though I needed a few tweaks to get it working how I wanted. In particular the following also handles:

- Avoiding the "jumpiness" on page load by first marking invisible and setting visible in javascript
- Dealing with browser resizes gracefully
- Additionally setting the footer back up the page if the browser gets smaller and the footer becomes bigger than the page
- Height function tweaks

Here's what worked for me with those tweaks:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer" class="invisible">My sweet footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function setFooterStyle() {
    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').outerHeight();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;
    if (footerTop < docHeight) {
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
    } else {
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', '');
    }
    $('#footer').removeClass('invisible');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setFooterStyle();
    window.onresize = setFooterStyle;
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me perfectly.

Add this class navbar-fixed-bottom to your footer.

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

I used it like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
<!-- start footer -->
</div>
```

And it sets to bottom over the the full width.

Edit: This will set footer to always visible, it's something you need to take in consideration.

Answer (score 10):

You need to wrap your `.container-fluid` div in order for your sticky footer to work, you're also missing some properties on your `.wrapper` class. Try this:

Remove the `padding-top:70px` from your `body` tag and include it in your `.container-fluid` instead, like so:

```
.wrapper > .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

We have to do this because pushing the `body` down to accommodate the navbar ends up pushing the footer a bit further (70px further) past the viewport so we get a scrollbar. We get better results pushing the `.container-fluid` div instead.

Next we have to remove the `.wrapper` class outside your `.container-fluid` div and wrap your `#main` div with it, like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your footer of course has to be out of the `.wrapper` div so remove it from the `.wrapper div and place it outside, like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    ....
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid">
    ....
</footer><!--END .row-fluid-->
```

After thats all done, properly push your footer closer to your `.wrapper` class by using a negative margin, like so:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* ie7 fix */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -43px;
}
```

And that should work, though you're probably going to have to modify a few other things to make it work when the screen is resized, like resetting the height on the `.wrapper` class, like so:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
   .wrapper {
      height:auto;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is the right way to do it with Twitter Bootstrap and the new navbar-fixed-bottom class: (you have no idea how long I spent looking for this)

CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#footer .navbar{
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Bootstrap v4+ solution

Here's a solution that doesn't require rethinking the HTML structure or any additional CSS trickery involving padding:

```
<html style="height:100%;">
  ...
  <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    ...
    <main class="flex-grow-1">...</main>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
  ...
</html>
```

Note that this solution allows for footers with flexible heights, which particularly comes in handy when designing pages for multiple screen sizes with content wrapping when shrunk.

### Why this works

- `style="height:100%;"` makes the `<html>` tag take the whole space of the document.
- class `d-flex` sets `display:flex` to our `<body>` tag.
- class `flex-column` sets `flex-direction:column` to our `<body>` tag. Its children (`<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>` and any other direct child) are now aligned vertically.
- class `h-100` sets `height:100%` to our `<body>` tag, meaning it will cover the entire screen vertically.
- class `flex-grow-1` sets `flex-grow:1` to our `<main>`, effectively instructing it to fill any remaining vertical space, thus amounting to the 100% vertical height we set before on our `<body>` tag.

Working demo here: https://codepen.io/maxencemaire/pen/VwvyRQB

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more information on flexbox.

Comment: `h-100` class doesn't work properly, it is better to use `min-vh-100`.

Comment: @ikonuk What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work properly"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Because `h-100` class always depends on the parent elements height and may not work on some cases properly. Since we want footer at the bottom of the viewport it would be a good practice to use viewport height.

Comment: Again, define 'some cases'. Your argument about the parent dependency applies just the same to `min-width`. Which is why the `HTML` tag has a `height` of 100% in the code. The example works and I don't see why it wouldn't given the [cross-browser support for the CSS `height` property](https://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh), which is ultimately what the Bootstrap snippet translates into.

Comment: I didn't say your example doesn't work. Not everyone uses the style in the `HTML` tag. In my case, your solution didn't work since I don't prefer using the style in the `HTML` tag. And I don't want the `body` tag depends on another parent but viewport. You don't have to put `style="height:100%;"` and `h-100` at the same time. Putting `min-vh-100` to the body simply does the job and less code.

Answer (score 4):

Use the navbar component and add .navbar-fixed-bottom class:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>
```

add body

```
  { padding-bottom: 70px; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Bootstrap 4.3 example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/), in case you're losing your sanity like I did, this is how it actually works:

- All parents of the footer div need to have `height: 100%` (`h-100` class)
- The direct parent of the footer needs to have `display: flex` (`d-flex` class)
- The footer needs to have `margin-top: auto` (`mt-auto` class)

The problem is that in modern front-end frameworks we often have additional wrappers around these elements.

For example in my case, with Angular, I composed the view from a separate app root, main app component, and footer component - all of which added their custom element to the DOM.

So, to make it work, I had to add classes to these wrapper elements: an additional `h-100`, moving the `d-flex` one level down, and moving the `mt-auto` one level up from the footer (so actually it's not on the footer class anymore, but on my `<app-footer>` custom element).

Comment: I had to put `class="h-100"` to the `<html>` tag too.

Comment: +1 for "The **direct** parent of the footer needs to have `d-flex` class". I had another `<div>` in the hierarchy between the `d-flex` one and the `footer`..

Answer (score 3):

to handle width constraint layouts use the following so that you do not get rounded corners, and so that your nav bar will be flush to the sides of the application

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="width-constraint clearfix">
            <p class="pull-left muted credit">YourApp v1.0.0</p>

            <p class="pull-right muted credit">©2013 • CONFIDENTIAL ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then you can use css to override the bootstrap classes to adjust height, font, and color

```
    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
        min-height: 22px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .p {
        margin: 2px 0 2px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to handle this:

```
$(function() {
    /**
     * Read the size of the window and reposition the footer at the bottom.
     */
    var stickyFooter = function(){
        var pageHeight = $('html').height();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();

        // A footer with 'fixed-bottom' has the CSS attribute "position: absolute",
        // and thus is outside of its container and counted in $('html').height().
        var totalHeight = $('footer').hasClass('fixed-bottom') ?
            pageHeight + footerHeight : pageHeight;

        // If the window is larger than the content, fix the footer at the bottom.
        if (windowHeight >= totalHeight) {
            return $('footer').addClass('fixed-bottom');
        } else {
            // If the page content is larger than the window, the footer must move.
            return $('footer').removeClass('fixed-bottom');
        }
    };

    // Call when this script is first loaded.
    window.onload = stickyFooter;

    // Call again when the window is resized.
    $(window).resize(function() {
        stickyFooter();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest technique is probably to use Bootstrap `navbar-static-bottom` in conjunction with setting the main container div with `height: 100vh` (new CSS3 [view port percentage](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)). This will flush the footer to the bottom.

```
<main class="container" style="height: 100vh;">
  some content
</main>      
<footer class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom">
  <div class="container">
  <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">&copy; Footer4U</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested with `Bootstrap 3.6.6`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <footer>
    <!-- your footer content here -->
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only one that worked for me!:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:90px;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of code in bootstrap it's works

```
<div class="navbar fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
 <p class="muted credit">Footer <a href="http://google.com">Link</a> and <a 
href="http://google.com/">link</a>.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
/*Negative indent footer by its height*/
margin: 0 auto -60px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

The footer height matches the size of the bottom indent of the wrap element.

```
.footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

```
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You may need to also offset the height of the footer by adding a `margin-bottom` equivalent to the footer height to the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for the newest version of Bootstrap (4.3 at time of writing) using Flexbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And a codepen example: https://codepen.io/tillytoby/pen/QPdomR

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `height:100%` 'chain' is being broken at `div#main`.  Try adding `height:100%` to it and that may get you closer to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find the approach in HAML ( http://haml.info )  with navbar on top and footer at the bottom of the page:

```
%body
  #main{:role => "main"}
    %header.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
      %nav.navbar-inner
        .container
          /HEADER
      .container
        /BODY
    %footer.navbar.navbar-fixed-bottom
      .container
        .row
          /FOOTER
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit? Code-only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: Okay, what do you want to know?

Comment: I don't need to know it, but someone coming to this site later might not know exactly *why* your answer's code does what it does.

Comment: Probably I should delete it. I wrote a new intro. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using css3:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);     /* Chrome */
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);     /* Firefox */
    min-height: calc(100% - 100px);     /* native */
}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container clear-top">
       body content....
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    footer content....
</footer>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/637j2cfw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how bootstrap does it:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Just use page source and you should be able to see. Don' forget the `<div id="wrap">` an the top.

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution, just using media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:767px) {
    .footer {
    }
}
/* no style for smaller or else it goes weird.*/
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .footer{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .footer{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1120px){
    .footer{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below class to push it to last line of the page and also make it to center of it.
If you are using ruby on rails HAML page you can make use of the below code.
`%footer.card.text-center`

Pls don't forget to use twitter bootstrapp

Answer (score 0):

this works well

html

```
<footer></footer>
```

css

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:90px;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5**

Add these classes

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">

<footer class="footer mt-auto">
```

Reference: https://radu.link/make-footer-stay-bottom-page-bootstrap/

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    <!-- navbar and containers here -->
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
   <!-- your footer here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  padding-bottom: 100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; /* Adjust to the footer needs */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is the best!

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:90px;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to bother explaining what is happening in the css code?