# positioning a div at bottom of the container element

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

Layout of the web page i am designing is like this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5sTub/

**EDIT: NOTE: I am not trying to get a sticky footer. i just want to position it at bottom of the page. Please see the fiddle before you answer**

i am trying to position the footer at the bottom of the page but am unable to as you can see in the link above. i have tried everything i found on the internet including setting the container element's position:relative; and the footer's `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;` but nothing seems to be working, in fact, if you add the container div to the code and make its `position:relative;`, and add the following css to footer : `position:absolute; bottom: 0;` , the footer seems to disappear somewhere. I've been struck on this problem since quiet a long time and the only solution i've found so far is to set my header and my content and the footer's `position:static;` , which dosent server the purpose and ruins whole layout and looks quiet ugly. I want to avoid the use of javascript. please help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Illustration of what i need:**
[image]

where blue is the footer, dark blue is header, light blue is actual content and pink one is a sticky div. i do not want to make footer sticky, but i want it to be like one you'll find on a normal page, only problem is that it dosent stay at the bottom of the page (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sTub/))

Comment: I think this is the most confusing question I've _ever_ seen on SO. If you just want your footer at the bottom of the page, just don't give it a position, and it'll sit below the content. I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: No, it dosent sit below the content, thats what the problem was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it help http://jsfiddle.net/5sTub/1/

Comment: **side note for people with same kind of problem**: in order to set the height of #wrapper in percentages in the fiddle above, you'll have to set the height of body first! , and most probably, you'd want to set the height of your body in percentages too!

Answer (score 2):

Use this

add this css property in your css

```
html, body{height:100%}


div#footer {
        color: white;
        background: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.8);
        width: 100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: as i said, and i repeat myself again, I am not looking for a fixed or sticky footer. i just wanna position it at bottom of the page !

Comment: "bottom of the page" is ambiguous! Everybody is taking a best guess at what you want to do, so please explain the behaviour you want better.

Comment: sorry if i have not mademyself clear. i now have added a simple illustration to help you guys understand my question better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Sticky Footer** method for this. Read this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

For example write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
 height:100%;
}
.container{
 min-height:100%;
}
.footer{
 height:40px;
 margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Check this for more [Flushing footer to bottom of the page, twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap/10099486#10099486)

Comment: not looking for a sticky footer, but instead i want to position it at bottom of the page

Comment: If my answer is not what you want then @rohit answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you resolved this or not, however I ran into a similar problem and resolved as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" " http://w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<style type="text/css" >
div#mypage {
    top:0;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
}
div#pageheader {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 20%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background: green;
    color: white;
 }
div#pagecontent {
}
div#contentleft {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    left:0%;
    right: 15%;
    width:15%;
    height: 92.5%;
    top: 5%;
    color: white;
}
div#contentcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    left:15%;
    right: 30%;
    width:80%;
    height: 92.5%;
    top: 5%;
    color: black;
}
div#contentright {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    left:95%;
    right: 5%;
    width:5%;
    height: 92.5%;
    top: 5%;
    color: white;
}
div#pagefooter {
    color: white;
    background: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
</style>
<head>
<title>Multiple Div's</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#cccccc">
<div id="mypage">
    <div id="pageheader">HDR</div>
    <div id="pagecontent">PAGE CONTENT
        <div id="contentleft">LEFT</div>
        <div id="contentcenter">CENTER</div>
        <div id="contentright">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div id="pagefooter">FOOTER</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?