# Sticky footer on Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sticky-footer, twitter-bootstrap-2

I want my bootstrap page to have it's footer always on the bottom of the page, and the solutions I've found aren't working for me. None of the solutions proposed here

[Flushing footer to bottom of the page, twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap) isn't working for me. As the height of the pages vary, it's tricky, right? No matter what I try, there's always whitespace below the footer. And as I don't want a **fixed footer**, how I'm supposed to achieve this, as my bootstrap site is responsive?

Comment: This? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: @rrikesh it works on pages that naturally have a scrollbar... But pages that have less content don't work, as there's a huge amount of whitespace.

Comment: you don't want whitespace above it, you don't want whitespace below it...what exactly is it that you want?

Comment: @mihai whitespace in between doesn't matter, when did I say that there can't be any whitespace before the footer?

Comment: I'm currently using the sticky-footer example, and it puts the footer at the very bottom of the page even if there isnt any content between the footer and the top of the page, so there is a lot of whitespace there (between the header and the footer). If you follow the example, I'm sure you can get it working. make sure your margins and heights are set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just have to stick with this:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: This doesn't work particularly well if there is more than just a few words of text and the viewport width is reduced substantially.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'm missing something, but this does not work "straight out of the box"

Comment: @SgtPooki it does, if you do it correctly. Easiest to start with the template and edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: https://gist.github.com/aalaap/3066704

I had to make a few adjustments to get it working with Bootstrap but it works well and does not require a fixed height footer, which is responsive.