# Push footer to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstarp for my site.

and using this thread to push my footer to bottom.

[Flushing footer to bottom of the page, twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap)

you can see my page here.

http://khanawal.com/MYListings.aspx

Please let me know where i'm going wrong or what css modifications I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Bootstrap's site provides an example for sticky footer. You can check them out for both versions: **[version 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html)** and **[version 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)**

Comment: I dont want sticky footer..just the one at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

add these attributes to your footer css:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you entire page is within your `form` tags. I would close the form tags at the top where required and set 100% height to the wrap div. I set height to 100% on google dev tools, for the form for testing and it fixed the issue.