# Boostrap 3: How do I create a footer that is at the bottom of the page, but isn't sticky / fixed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I need it so the footer is at the very bottom of the page but only when the user actually scrolls there.

I can't use margin-bottom: -50px; because the pages have different sizes, that specific length only works on one page.

Comment: does this post help you? [flushing footer at bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: This is the technique that's usually used for BS 3: http://bootply.com/108574