# Footer bootstrap

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a little problem with the bootstrap I would like to add a footer to my site I want it to be all at the bottom of the page

My code :

```
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <h4>Developped By Dev-Sofiane</h4>
</footer>
```

I need this :

[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flushing footer to bottom of the page, twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099422/flushing-footer-to-bottom-of-the-page-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a very less content on the page. If you still want your footer to the bottom, give the content section a `min-height: 100vh` like below snippet.

Thanks me later.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<footer class="footer1">Footer 1</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set in css the footer to position fixed, and if you then set the bottom to 0 the footer should be at the bottom.