# fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make fixed header and footer visible at the bottom of the screen/page all times.

Main code below works fine if the header is not fixed. If enable this little part in css, footer gets messed up. If I don't then header doesn't get fixed.

```
/*
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
*/
```

Is there any chance help modifying mode?

Examples looked:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height), [2](http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/), [3](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) and some others.

Thanks in advance

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,'DejaVu Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    background: #BABABA;
}
#container 
{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header
{
    display: block;
    /*
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    */
    padding: 10px 10px 11px 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #000000;
}
#body
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    /*background: #ff0000;*/
}
#footer
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    padding: 9px 0px 3px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777777;
    background: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
        <p>Hello</p><br />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change #footer to position fixed

Comment: removed `html, body: height: 100%;` removed `#container: min-height: 100%;` enabled commented css code and it wokrs fine now with fixed footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't want your footer to be fixed, but it doesn't touch the bottom of the screen ?

If that's your problem, you should do this :

```
#header{
    height: 40px;
}

#container{
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

If you want you footer to be displayed on the bottom of the page, you should just set his position to fixed

```
#footer{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: removed `html, body: height: 100%;` removed `#container: min-height: 100%;` enabled commented css code and it wokrs fine now with `footer fixed`.