# Sticky footer. html

Tags: html, css, footer

I have this very simple footer :

```
.footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0px; 
}
```

and this container :

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

The container's (content) height is 100% so it is based on the amount of results you get from your search query. I want the footer to stick underneith the container at all time. And when you have no results I just want to have it at the bottom of the screen.

I tried to give the container a padding-bottom the height of the container and change the posistion but it didn't help. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: How about using a little JQuery ? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9uFY/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
.footer{ width:100%; background-color:#333; height:100px; position: fixed;
bottom: 0px; }
```

Changing position absolute with fixed

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5dGVf/)**

Comment: that dindt change anything, still stciks at the bottom of the screen, and doesnt adjust to the height of the container

Answer (score -1):

see this [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

and http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page
I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: When I have 0 results its just floating half-way like the image. Any clue?

Comment: Tried, dindt work. I tried it in a jsfiddle and it worked, but as soon as my gridview gets more then 20 results the footer stil floats

Comment: make a jsfiddle of your design

Comment: try this .container{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
}     give height:auto;.

Comment: @Pawan JSFiddle doesnt allow ASP.NET. the mark-up is identical to to your first link. Except that the asp.net gridview doesnt seem to recognice any height