# footer stuck in middle of page div not filling remain screen

Tags: css, html, opacity, sticky-footer

So I'm updating a local circus website and the footer does not want to stay at the bottom of the page. I don't want it fixed to the bottom of the screen but rather when you scroll to the bottom of the content that's where the footer should be. I'm also trying to use a div to fill the remaining space to the right of the buttons with a semi opaque black background. The site should look like this http://sdrv.ms/18Njjnw but instead it looks like http://sdrv.ms/17PkpdR. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<body>
<div id="body">
<a href="index.html" ><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="circus logo" /></a>
<div id="buttons" >
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="circus.html"> Circus </a></div>
<div id="currentPage" class="opa"> <a class="buttons" href="tickets.html"> Tickets </a></div>
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="performers.html"> Performers </a></div>
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="band.html"> Circus City Band </a></div>
<div class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="festival.html"> Circus City Festival </a></div>
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="calendar.html"> Calendar </a></div>
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="about.html"> About </a></div>
<div  class="opa"><a class="buttons"  href="forms.html"> Forms </a></div>
</div>


<div id="contentContain" >

<div id="paragraph">
    <h1> Order Tickets 
    </h1>

    <p> 

Performance Dates
<br />
Family Night:<br />

Friday, July 12, 2013 - 7 p.m.<br />
General admission seating - $5.00<br />
Tickets go on sale the day of show!<br />
<br />
Regular Performances:<br />
Saturday, July 13 - 2 p.m. & 7 p.m. <br />
Sunday, July 14 - 3 p.m. <br />
Monday - Friday, July 15-19 - 7 p.m. <br />
Saturday, July 20 - 2 p.m. & 7 p.m. <br />
<br />
Order Online, at the Box Office, or by calling us at 765.472.3918


rom the barn to the big top, Circus has<br /> been a part of Peru, Indiana for over 100 years. Exp<br />erience a walk through Peru's circus history at the Circus City Museum. This popular Museum, locat<br />ed in the Circus City Center, is filled with photos,<br /> miniatures, displays, and costumes from circus past. The museum is open Monday through Friday, A<br />pril through September from 9 am to 5 pm and October throu<br />gh March 9 am to 4 pm. During circus week enjoy<br /> the many circus wagons displayed outs<br />ide the museum as well as extended hours before and after each circus performance. Admission is by <br />donation only. Group tours can be scheduled<br /> by contacting the Circus office at 765-472-3918.

Monetary and ar<br />tifact donations are accepte<br />d and greatly appreciated.  

For monetary donations se<br />nd check or Mon<br />ey order to: 
Circus City Museum
C/O Circus City Fest<br />ival Inc.
154 N. Broadway
Peru Indiana. 
<br /><br />
Circus artifacts can al<br />so be mailed, delivered, or picked up.  
Contact the Circus City Fes<br /><br />tivals office at 765-472-3918 for more details.

Circus City Gift Shop<br />
Complete your “Big Top” ex<br /><br />perience with a souvenir from our Circus City Gift Shop! Memorabilia such as post cards, t-shirts, hats, toys, and more are <br />available for purchase. The gift shop is located in the <br />Circus City Center and is open to the public Monday through Friday, <br />April through September from 9 am to 5 pm and October through March from 9 am to 4 pm.<br /> Proceeds are used to support Circus City Festivals, Inc. <br />and the Peru Amateur Youth Circus program.


    </p>


    <div id="ticketsbut" ><a id="order"  href="http://sa1.seatadvisor.com/sabo/servlets/EventSearch?presenter=CIRCUSCITY">Place Ticket Order  </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"> </div>
</div>




<a href="http://www.firstbankofberne.com/"><img id="bank" src="images/bank.png" /></a>
<div id="footer" >

<p id="foottext"> Circus City Festival, Inc.&nbsp; •&nbsp; 154 North Broadway&nbsp; •&nbsp;  Peru, IN 46970 &nbsp;•  &nbsp;(765) 472-3918&nbsp; •&nbsp;  Fax:(765) 472-2826 &nbsp;•  &nbsp;info@perucircus.com </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
</html>

body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
html{

}


div.sidebar{
background-color:black;
width:35%;
min-width:430px;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: .5;
}

#body{
position:relative;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%
}

#foottext{

}


#contentContain{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:430px;

height:auto;
z-index:1000;
color:white;
}

#content{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: .5;

height:100%;
z-index:-1;

}
#paragraph{
text-align:center;
}

#sideBarContainer{
height:100%;
}

#logo{
width:420px;
z-index:1000;
}

#footer{
background-color:black;
width:100%;
height:35px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
text-align:center;
color: white;
z-index:1000;
}

a.buttons{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
height:35px;
line-height:35px;
text-align:center;
font-family: Lucida Bright;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#currentPage{
background-color:black;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: .5;
}
#currentPage:hover{
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 100;
}

a.buttons:hover{
background-color:black;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 100;
}

#buttons{
width:430px;
}

#bank{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position will takes its position from its relative containing div.  It looks like its taking it from the window.  If you put a position:relative in the container div.

You can also look into position:fixed but that has limited browser support.

Regardless, you want to have the footer positioned inline (the natural state of the divs) so pull all that out.

Comment: There is a body div tag that it should be taking it's position from. #body{
position:relative;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%
}

Also, what do you mean "pull all that out"?

Comment: put a container div in your body with a relative position declared.  Get rid of the height/width declared heights...that might be what is causing the problem.  When I said "pull all that out" I mean take it out of the code and code the divs inline....probably too much work at this point but coding everything with absolute positioning isn't the best practice

Comment: What do you mean by "limited browser support"?  Are you referring to mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fixed positioning?  This should do it:

```
#footer{
position: fixed;
}
```

EDIT:
Are you looking for something like this?
[CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

Comment: I want the footer to be at the bottom of any given page so if the content spills past the window size you would have to scroll down to the bottom to see the footer. However, if the content doesn't spill past the page the footer should just display at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If you are going to use this make sure you look into browser compatibility issues.