# Position footer at bottom of page having fixed header

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I want to position the footer at the bottom of the page which having a fixed header also...

- **Not with `position: fixed`** - I don't want it to remain on the screen, it should just be at the end of the page and behave normally when scrolling.
- **Not at the bottom of the visible screen** - At the bottom of the **page**, i.e; after all other content.

---

**Here's a diagram to explain better:**

[image: Footer problem]

---

**Here's the code:**

- I have prepared a demo: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FP5KU/)**
- Or see below

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Some content...</p>    
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

```css
body{
    /* Just to enable scrolling in JSFiddle */
    height: 1000px;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; /*Height of header*/
    z-index: 0;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/*For demo only*/
#header, #footer{
    border: 3px dashed #333333;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#content{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the formatting of the code. If anyone can edit I'd appreciate.

Comment: Are you using IE? Formatting does be messed up when I view it in IE!

Comment: Does `content` need to has `absolute` position?

Comment: Why not just using some relative positions for your content and your footer? i mean you use a margin-top : 100px; for content and you just put the footer after it.

Comment: @HashemQolami, I think so. Because the header has fixed position, so it makes sure that the content is visible.

Comment: Ok I don't get what's wrong. In your demo the footer is positioned at the bottom of all your content like you want

Comment: Then remove position absolute on the content, and instead give it a top margin the same size as the header height

Comment: @Drahcir I've just updated my answer with two alternative solution, please let me know how it works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you have mentioned, `position: fixed` would position the footer with the respect to the viewport rather than the page itself. Therefore, we have to keep the element in normal flow and somehow position it to the bottom of the page.

There are couple of approaches to achieve that, which have been discussed *in the wild* during the time.
For instance:

- [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/)'s article [Exploring Footers](http://alistapart.com/article/footers/) - by *[Bobby Van Der Sluis](https://twitter.com/bsluis)*, 2004
- [footerStickAlt](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/) - by *[Craig Erskine](https://twitter.com/craigerskine/)*, 2005
- [Sticky Footer](http://brassblogs.com/css/sticky-footer) - by *[Shelly Cole](https://twitter.com/brassblogs)*, 2006
- [How to keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) - by *[Matthew James Taylor](http://twitter.com/mattjamestaylor)*, 2007
- [Make the Footer Stick to the Bottom of a Page](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) - by *[Ryan Fait](https://twitter.com/ryanfait)*, 2007
- [Refined version of Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) - by *[Chris Coyier](http://twitter.com/chriscoyier)*, 2009
- [Sticky CSS footers: The flexible way](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/) *(which uses [CSS Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display))* - by *[Torben Haase](https://github.com/letorbi)*, 2011
- [Responsive Sticky Footer](http://www.joshrcook.com/a-responsive-sticky-footer/) *(refined version of Torben's approach)* - by *[Joshua Cook](https://twitter.com/joshrcook)*, 2013
- [Solved by Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)'s [Sticky Footer](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) - by *[Philip Walton](https://twitter.com/philwalton)*, 2013

### Sticky Footer

In this answer I'd go with [Ryan Fait's method](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) since it is simple and easy to understand and also it meets your needs *(Situations where both header and footer have fixed heights)*.

Considering the structure below:

```
<div id="content"> <!-- content goes here. It may (not) include the header --> </div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

The following steps are needed:

1. Setting `height` of the `<html>` and `<body>` elements to `100%` which is required for the next step<sup>1</sup>.
2. The most important thing we need to do is to make sure that the `#content` is high enough to push the `#footer` down the page. Hence we give the `#content` a `min-height` of `100%`.
3. [So far](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w9y6ytLe/), the `#content` has taken `100%` of height of the viewport, thus we should pull the footer up to position it at the bottom of the page. In order to do that we could give the `#content` a negative `margin-bottom` equivalent to the footer's `height`. Also to make sure that the footer appears on top of the content, we should `position` the footer `relative`ly. **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w9y6ytLe/5/)**.
4. As can be seen, when the `#content` grows by its contents, some of the contents go behind the footer. We could avoid that either by appending a spacer element at the end of `#content` or use the combination of `padding-bottom` and [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)<sup>2</sup> which is supposed to be [supported on IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) as well.

#### 4.1 Adding a spacer

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w9y6ytLe/6/)**

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

```css
.spacer, #footer { height: 100px; }
```

#### 4.2 Combination of `padding-bottom` and `box-sizing`

**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w9y6ytLe/7/)**

```css
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px; /* Equivalent to footer's height */
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* Equivalent to footer's height */

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*(Note that vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity)*

---

### Adding the Header

1. If the header should remain **in normal flow**, you could simply add it to the `#content` as follows:
   (**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hgm4ng3x/1/)**)

   ```
   <div id="content">
       <div id="header">Header</div>
       ...
   ```
2. But if it should be **positioned absolutely**<sup>3</sup>, we need to push the contents of `#content` element down in order [to prevent overlapping](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w9y6ytLe/9/).

Therefore, again, we could either add a spacer at the beginning of `#content` (**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hgm4ng3x/2/)**):

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="header-spacer"></div> 
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <div class="footer-spacer"></div> 
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Or use the combination of `padding-top` and `box-sizing` as follows:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content"> <!-- content goes here. --> </div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

```css
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px; /* Equivalent to footer's height */

    padding-top   : 50px;  /* Equivalent to header's height */
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* Equivalent to footer's height */

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hgm4ng3x/3/)** *(Note that vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity)*

### At last but not least!

Nowadays, All major modern web browsers support [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) declaration (including IE8). However if you're looking for the traditional way which has a wider browser support, stick with using spacer elements.

---

<sup>1. This is needed to make [`min-height: 100%`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights) to work on the `#content` element (because a percentage value is relative to the `height` of the box's containing block which is established by the `<body>`). Also `<html>` should have an explicit [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height) to make `height: 100%` to work on `<body>`.</sup>

<sup>2. [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing) makes UAs calculate the `width`/`height` of the box including padding and borders.</sup>

<sup>3. [According to spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned), absolutely positioned elements are elements having a `position` of `absolute` or `fixed`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is working great for me. I'm using JSFiddle #1, but I removed box sizing, it seems to be working on all browsers (including IE7) - http://jsfiddle.net/33vQy/2/

Comment: @Drahcir You're welcome :) In fact, in this case, `box-sizing: border-box;` prevents page from scrolling when it is not needed.

Comment: Outstanding explanation

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. What you need is a container.

Here is my revised bit:
[JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/FP5KU/4/)

Add a container div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="page"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Then make the position relative, and the height 100%:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

And make sure the position is absolute for the footer.

Comment: The problem is that if I remove the body `height` property, then it stops working.

Answer (score 3):

Or for those who found this post by googling and want an even shorter answer, without wrappers (because you don't need them):

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; position: relative; padding-bottom: 3em; }
.footer { height: 3em; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

done, the page is now at least 100% screen height, and the footer is at the bottom of the page, not the bottom of "the screen". If the page is longer than the screen, it'll still be at the bottom, and we did it without artificial "wrapper elements" or the likes: the `body` element is already the wrapper we need =)

The only caveat is that the body margin needs to be the same as the footer height, but then as negative value, since the "bottom: 0" rule will make the footer start *at the bottom* instead of baseline-anchored. Then again, as CSS, .less or .styl, this is trivially ensured.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the punctuation ":" after the word "bottom". After correcting that the code worked ok!

Answer (score 0):

To do it simple:

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;
}
#content, #footer {
    position: relative; /* or leave it static as by default */
    z-index:1;
}
body,div {
    margin:0; padding:0; /* http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css */
}
#content {
    margin-top: 100px; /* the same value as header's height */
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3whx9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
But if you want the footer to take full size of the screen while #wrapper is 1000px and centered you would do:


<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-inner">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

html,
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#wrapper-inner {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}
#content {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at web development, and I know this has been answered already, but this is the easiest way I found to solve it and I  think is somehow different. I wanted something flexible because my footer can have different heights on different sections of the web app. And I ended up using FlexBox and a spacer.

1. Start by setting the height for your html and body

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I'm assuming a `column` behavior for our app, in the case you need to add a header, hero or any content vertically aligned.

2. Create the spacer class

```css
.spacer {
    flex: 1; 
}
```

3. So later on your HTML could be something like

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header> Header </header>
    Some content...
    <div class='spacer'></div>
    <footer> Footer </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can play with it here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmGZQL