# Pushing the footer at the bottom of my page with a margin at the top

Tags: html, css, footer

I often use the method of an empty `div` to make my footer stay at the bottom of my page. The code idea is following:

```
<body>
    <div id="canevas">
        <article>My website's content</article>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">Here my footer</footer>
</body>
```

The css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
}
#canevas {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -33px;
}
#footer, #push {
    height: 33px;
}
```

Today I'm looking for **how to add a margin-top** on my `#caneva div` without breaking the footer. Do you have any idea?

Note that my page's content can have many different size (a lot less and a lot more than 100% of the screen height).

[Here a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/FEW96/2/) with previous code.

Comment: Couldn't this all be achieved without the empty div?

Comment: @88MPG The empty div is required when the page is fulfilled. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/FEW96/4/).

Comment: try `#canevas{height:calc(100%-100px);}` 100px being the margin-top value.

Comment: @Fractaliste There is a solution if using `padding-top` is an option (instead of `margin-top`).

Comment: Just decrease your margin-bottom by an additional 30px to match the added margin top: http://jsfiddle.net/FEW96/5/

Comment: @HashemQolami I've tested it without success : http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/FEW96/6/

Comment: @Fractaliste That's not the way :) http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/FEW96/9/

Comment: @David good idea the overflow-hidden, but it make an issue when the page is fulfilled : http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/FEW96/10/

Comment: Well the overflow-hidden is not required, it just kept it from still scrolling beyond your footer. Why aren't you just fixing the footer with positioning?

Comment: @Fractaliste Not sure exactly about why you need `margin-top`, but if you're looking for adding an internal space at the top of the content, you could refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page/18469622#18469622

Comment: @HashemQolami Your answer looks good, thanks, I didn't know `bored-box` comportment. I'm going to have a look to your link ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [`padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top) is an option, you could use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to calculate the *width* and *height* of the box including *padding* and *border*, as follows:

```css
#canevas {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -33px;

    padding-top: 50px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/FEW96/9/)**.

Also it's worth noting that `border-box` value [is supported on IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility).

Alternatively, you could add another *spacer* element as the first child of the `#canevas` element to push down the content, as follows:

```css
.spacer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="canevas">
        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <article>My website's content</article>

        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">Here my footer</footer>
</body>
```

This will have a promising browser support :)

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/FEW96/13/)**.

For further info, you could refer my answer on a similar question on SO here:

- [Position footer at bottom of page having fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page/18469622#18469622)

Comment: +1, Just note that this is only partially supported in any browser other than Firefox right now, and is unsupported in IE 7.0-.

Comment: While I'm not arguing either side's point, the percentage you pointed out is of the browsers tested on that site, not of actual use percentages or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to keep the height of the page, then the answer is to also add `margin-bottom: -63px;` to your `#caneva div`. This way basically only the top of the '#caneva div' will change, the rest of the page will remain the same.

I created an updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FEW96/14/) for you.

Comment: You just need to fix the footer. That works in any browser. I amended my fiddle now...