# Basic layout with zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I’m trying to create layout using zurb foundation.

Currently, I’ve got very basic one, but one feature blocks me on that very beginning.
I’d like to make my `<main>` section to take at least 100% - header height - footer height, so `<footer>` would be on the bottom of the screen (or, if there is too much content, then you’d have to scroll down to see footer)
I created (as I said before, very basic version) here: http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/2/

I’m not sure if it’s possible without JS, but I’d much more prefer CSS based solution.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page/18469622#18469622

Comment: Here is an implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/3/

Comment: Yet another one: http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/4/

Comment: Well, this one is almost OK, however, as you’ve probably seen, sidebar/content section does not take 100% available height :/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/5/ This is a bit complex, but if you have any question, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Oh, this looks nearly as something I’d like to achieve, but when I’ve got less content, then I see golden background (taken fron <main>), instead of having my sidebar+content section (almost) 100% height.

Comment: Okay then, here's my last attempt to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/6/ Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for what you are looking, however its not done in foundation.

http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/full/lmrgD

Its done using `position: absolute` to `footer`.

Importantly you done need js for that.

Even if content increases the footer move down.

Comment: Hi, thanks – tip with ```position: absolute``` is nice, but still my sidebar+content section isn’t 100% height (and equal in height, regardless on its content height).

Comment: correct me If am wrong....you want the footer to be at bottom even if content in the page is less?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the height for the main section to your requirement.

here is a fiddle with a class(main) for section 100%.[link](http://jsfiddle.net/42VcD/7/)

```
.main{
height:100%;
}
```