# FireFox send footer to bottom

Tags: css

My footer will not stick to the bottom of the page in the latest Firefox, while it works in Chrome and IE11. From what I can tell the min-height:100% for the wrapper has no effect in Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<div id = "wrapper">
  <div id = "content">
  </div>
  <div id = "push">
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -235px;
}
#push{
    height:235px;
}

    #footer{
    position:relative;
    height:235px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Does `#wrapper` div located directly into `<body>` as a child element?

Comment: It doesn't work on any browser for me Safari, Chrome or FF... Why not use `bottom:0;` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say by the posted code but according to [CSS level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/):

> **[10.7 Minimum and maximum heights: 'min-height' and 'max-height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights)**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, **the percentage
>   value is treated as '0'** (for 'min-height') or 'none' (for
>   'max-height').

Hence you should make sure that the parent of `#wrapper` has an explicit `height`. If the `#wrapper` is located in `<body>`, try specifying `height: 100%` on `<body>` and `<html>` elements as well:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Because [a percentage value for `height` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x12) is relative to the height of the generated box's containing block as well, in this case the `<html>`. Otherwise the value computes to `auto`.

In addition, using `height: auto !important;` and `height: 100%;` together doesn't make sense and they're pointless; So it's better to remove them.

```css
#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -235px;
}
```

Finally if it didn't work, you could give the following approach a try:

- [Position footer at bottom of page having fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page/18469622#18469622)

Comment: Thanks - adding height:100% to the body was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify what you have a little.

- Your `#push` can be replaced with the pseudo element `:after` on your wrapper.
- Remove the height on the wrap and avoid `!important`.
- `html,body` needs to have a height of 100% in order for other elements to have percentage heights

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/joquri/2/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <!-- main content -->
</div>    
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -235px; 
}
.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.footer, .wrap:after {
  height: 235px; 
}
.footer {
  background: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Tested and working IE8+, should also work in IE6/7, but can't remember :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have your your footer stick to the bottom, use:

```
#footer{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   height:235px;
   width:100%;
}
```

I just tried it with your code and verified that it works on the latest firefox.

Comment: I cannot use this because if the page is long it will appear on top of elements.