# How to make the footer stick to the bottom?

Tags: css, html

I was building a portfolio website purely out of html5 and css and I am stuck at sticking the footer at the bottom of the page.

Here are the codes:

contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>contact | sadman s.</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>sadman s.</h1>
    </header>

    <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/code/index.html">h o m e</a></li>
            <li><a href="/code/blog.html">b l o g</a></li>
            <li><a href="/code/portfolio.html">p o r t f o l i o</a></li>
            <li><a href="/code/about.html">a b o u t</a></li>
            <li><a href="/code/contact.html">c o n t a c t</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--NAVIGATION BAR ENDS-->

<!--BODY STARTS HERE-->
<body>

    <form>

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Name">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND">

    </form>

</body>
<!--BODY ENDS HERE-->

<!--FOOTER STARTS HERE-->
<footer>
    <div id="footer_line"></div>

    <!--FOOTER LINKS BAR-->
<nav>
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/sadmanshawmik" target="blank"><span id="footer_bar">t w i t t e r</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/shawmikiki" target="blank"><span id="footer_bar">i n s t a g r a m</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/" target="blank"><span id="footer_bar">g i t h u b</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!--FOOTER BAR ENDS-->
<p>copyright © 2014 - <span id="footer_link"><a href="/code/index.html">sadman.de</a></span>. all rights reserved.</p>

</footer>

</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
        * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Droid Serif;
}

body {
    font-family: Droid Serif;
}

header {
    font-family: Droid Serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR*/

nav {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 25px 0 40px 0;
    padding: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Droid Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 32px 0 32px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #00d8a3;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

a:active {
    color: #00d8a3 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*BODY*/


h2 {
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Droid Serif;
}

table {
    border: 2px;
    margin: -10px auto 15px auto;
}

td {
    padding: 20px;
}

table tr td img {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

table tr td img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

#footer_line {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #696969;
    margin: auto;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

#footer_bar {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

#footer_link {
    color: #00d8a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer_link:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}



/*CONTACT FORM*/

label {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

form {
    width: 437px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#form-div {
    background-color: e1e1e1;
    padding: 35px 35px 50px 35px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -260px;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 27px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #696969;
}

textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border: 3px solid #00d8a3;
}

#submit {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #00d8a3;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 56px auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is an image of my homepage, I want the footer to be at the bottom of the contact page like in the homepage. http://puu.sh/bzOUo/e1f2479945.jpg

Here is how it is showing up in the contact page right now: http://puu.sh/bzOWZ/ef02a73399.png

Also, if someone can help me align the "send" button in the contact page with the rest of the input boxes, it'd be really nice.

Comment: TWO BODY TAG ??? and close only ONE ???

Comment: also it is good if you provide fiddle example

Comment: For button just add margin: 10px; for footer set height of form or set margin: 0 auto 182px; as you want footer down increase or decrease last pixel

Comment: This topic has been [discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?lq=1) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header?lq=1) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You can find lot of reference codes in [Css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try absolute position on footer

```
footer
{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4q1uzph/)**

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work out. add this to your css code :

```
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}
footer * {
  display:inline;
}
```