# How to adjust the height of the footer automatically

Tags: html, css

How do you adjust the height of the footer based on how long the div content inside the body is?

I've tried searching for a solution like having the position of the footer "fixed" but it isn't what I want because it's like stuck at the bottom of the screen. I want the footer to show when I reach the bottom of the page and change its height automatically when the main_content height changes as well since I've put the height of the main_content to auto. How can I do this?

Here's how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/cherry12345/t62b2qb6/

Heres my code:

HTML

```html
<body>
    <div  id="main_content">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2014-2015 example.com. All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
#main_content {
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:400px;
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
}   
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background: #666;
    padding: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You want the footer height to be proportional to the height to the main content area?

Comment: Could you expand on `[...] and change its height automatically when the main_content height changes.`?

Comment: Yes like have it at the bottom of the main content area. I made a lot of pages and they are all different in heights so I want the footer to be at the bottom of the main content however long the main content is

Comment: Then put it at the bottom of the `#content` div. You're trying too hard with positioning, it looks like.

Comment: So you really don't want to alter the `height` of the footer, do you?

Comment: Have a look at [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?lq=1). More explanation here: [Position footer at bottom of page having fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header).

Comment: this is called ***sticky footer***. See http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t62b2qb6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-arrange and drop the positioning and get it to work like this:

```
#main_content {
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
}
#main_content > p {
    margin-left: 440px;
}
#main_content > p:first-child {
    margin-top: 110px;
}
#footer {
    background: #666;
    padding: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}

<div id="main_content">
    <p>Some text</p>
    ...
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="footer">&copy; 2014-2015 mysite.com. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t62b2qb6/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would help:

```
#main_content {
    width:auto;
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
}   

#footer{
    width:100%;
    background: #666;
    padding: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t62b2qb6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Define your html as follow:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS (note that footer should be absolute, and wrapper be relative)

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3n52zt2h/