# How to keep the footer at bottom in asp.net master page.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, sticky-footer

i want to keep my footer at bottom in every child page.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<div class="footer">
footer content
</div>
```

Comment: Here you could find a good collection of sticky footers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the following CSS to the footer:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yau can put `ContentPlaceHolder` inside a `div` and set its `min-height` as per your requirement:

```
  <div style="min-height:500px;">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
```

It will occupy `min-height` whether there is data on `content page` or not.

Comment: but this is not my requirement right.? footer should be in bottom of every page

Comment: Then you should try some jquery sticky footers as suggested by @Hashem Qolami

Comment: Nice idea.. i was searching such adjustment for master page issue this since 2012 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
padding:10px;
background:#5ee;
}
#content {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:#ee5;
}
```