# Issue with sticky footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently shaping up my [code editor's webpage](http://osxpeppermint.com).

I had a sticky footer (meaning sticking to the bottom of the page, no matter what).

However, though I don't know how, all of a sudden I must have tweaked something and it went unstick again.

[image: Sticky footer]

And guess what, I cannot fix it. :S ( *I have to admit CSS was never really my thing...* )

Any ideas?

---

**P.S.** The issue is noticeable in all pages/subpages, not just the homepage.

---

**UPDATE:**

Guys, thanks a lot for your super-fast replies. I think you got it right. But not 100% - perhaps I didn't explain what I need it clearly.

Adding a `position:fixed` **does** fix it to the bottom. But, let's say in the homepage, the footer is above the content (like the top navbar). This is not what I needed. **By "sticky", I mean it has to stay at the bottom of the page. If it's a short page, then it'll appear at the bottom. If it's a long page, you'll see it only if you scroll at the very bottom of the page.**

Comment: why not make the content element a min-height: of xx % so that the footer will be at the bottom of the page without setting a position attr. Then when this content element has to much data in it, and the page scrolls, the footer will be still at the bottom of the page

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height? Also you could find a list of different methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am amazed no one has still managed to answer your question correctly, since you've explained it so clearly.

This is how you do it using only css. Let's say this is your html markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <p>Your website content here.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
     <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
</div>
```

The css should look like:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* equal to footer height: */
    margin-bottom: -140px;
 }

.footer {
    height: 140px;
}
```

Link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Yes your answer is by far the most complete (that's what I wanted basically). One more question: Please have a look at this page (http://osxpeppermint.com/category/themes). Why does the footer appear like 10px BELOW the page when the page loads?

Comment: In #main css: insead of **margin-top: 20px**, try using **padding-top: 20px;**

Comment: Hmm... Unfortunately I've tried that. And it doesn't seem to be working as I want it to...

Comment: Strange. This fixed the problem when I tried it online using Chome Developer Tools. What problem are you facing?

Comment: AWESOME. It worked!! I've been banging my head against the wall for sooooo long! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Yayy!! Finally had my first accepted answer. You're welcome :)

Comment: You're great. I'm sure you'll get many more accepted answers! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Change position of `#footer` to `fixed` seems to work fine.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/

**UPDATE**

After you update: remove the margin-bottom: 45px on the body element and add min-height: 100%

```
body {
    /* margin-bottom: 45px; */
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100% /* for short pages */
}
```

The footer position can then remain absolute.

**UPDATE**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you are faaast! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: So your issue is with the white spacing below the footer?

Comment: Well, I guess that's a nice way to put it. In any case, there must be no visible space below the footer.

Comment: Just tried (via safari console) your updated solution to the http://osxpeppermint.com/category/themes page. However, the footer is still not moving to the bottom. Have a look: http://i58.tinypic.com/24103z5.png

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that height of the html must be 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
...
```

to

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
...
```

Comment: Use `bottom:-45px;` then.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make something stick it should have a fixed position in your CSS.

You can find more about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Make sure your footer and all divs surrounding it are also set to fixed.

EDIT:

If you want your footer to appear only at the very bottom set the margin-bottom of your footer to 0px like this:

```
#footer {

    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #666;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,arial,freesans,clean;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just changed the position to fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need position fixed with bottom:0

```
 #footer {
position: fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are [couple of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header) to have a sticky footer at the bottom of the page. It seems you are using [Matthew James Taylor's method](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page), but there are coupe of mistakes within your code.

Assuming the given markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

You could follow the steps below to fix the issues and achieve the sticky footer:

1. `<html>` should have an explicit `height` of `100%`.
2. `<body>` should have:

   1. A `min-height` of `100%`.
   2. Relative positioning. i.e. `position: relative`.
   3. A bottom *padding* as the height of the sticky footer.
3. `#main` should have a top *padding* as the height of the fixed header (up to you).
4. `#footer` should be positioned `absolute`ly at the bottom - `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`.

Finally, set `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements `* {...}` to force the browser to calculate the size of boxes including borders and padding.

### Getting all together - [Example](http://jsbin.com/navaxu/1/edit?html,css,output)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { height: 100%; }

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 45px; /* height of the footer */
}

.navbar {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 30px; /* height of the fixed positioned header */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sticky footers are the easiest things: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c5qua6j5/)**

```
footer{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to undersand CSS better you should understand how the "position" value works.
The default value of all elements' in a html site is:

```
position:static;
```

For your own problem now the `position:fixed` is your solution but dont just use it and learn nothing by it.
You can easily experiment with position values to see how they work on the html document.

> For example, with position absolute at first and adding a animated
>   class with position fixed onscroll will give you a very nice scrolling effect.

You can check this very detailed article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position .
For the end i give you the answer:

```
   #footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

**/* UPDATE**

The sticky footer effect cannot be accomplished with pure CSS. The problem is that you need a function to measure your window's height and giving the footer the correct margin from the top. 
To accomplish that you can use this snippet of jQuery(hopefully you have jQuery installed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
  var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
  if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
    $("footer#colophon").css("position","absolute").css("bottom",0);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at my recent update please. `fixed` does not exactly do what I need.

Comment: I'm more than 100% sure that the more-knowledgeable than me in CSS would very much disagree with you in that there is not CSS-only solution to that. In fact, I have done in the past, and I had done it for this very website (however, I must have tweaked something which messed the whole thing up).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use javascript?
If so then you can run this javascript in the end of a page or in timeout:

---

EDIT (i am not forcing to use javascript, there are great CSS answers also :)

---

```
var setPosition = function(){
    var foot = document.getElementById('gridContainer2');
    foot.style.position = "relative";
    if((foot.offsetTop + foot.offsetHeight) >= window.innerHeight){
        foot.style.position = "fixed";
    }
    else{
        foot.style.position = "relative"; //or whatever you wish
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){
    setPosition();
    window.onresize = function(){setPosition();};
},10);
```

Comment: And what if the user resizes the window? Would I have to attach this to a window resize event? Sounds rather too much, doesn't it?