# How to make a footer that sticks to bottom when content is short but not fixed in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make a footer that sticks to the bottom when content is shorter than screen height and float to bottom of the content when content is longer than screen height ?Now I am doing like this.

html

```
<body>
<div class='container'>

</div>
<footer>

</footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  min-height:500px;
}

footer{
 height:200px;
 background-color:black;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
}
```

This code is fine when the content is shorter than the screen size or very short. But my issue is when the content is very much longer(eg.twice of the screen size), footer sticks to the bottom when it first loads the page. But when I scroll down, the footer is stacked to the top of the new scrolled content.

Comment: Best way, use Bootstrap class `fixed-bottom`.

Comment: He wants it to be at the bottom of the document when it extends beyond the viewport, but at the bottom of the viewport otherwise.

Comment: For more info on sticky footers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469262/position-footer-at-bottom-of-page-having-fixed-header

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var containerHeight = $('.container').outerHeight(true);
    var windowHeight = $('window').height();
    if(containerHeight < windowHeight ){
       $('footer').css('position','fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is how to do it with jQuery, but it should be done with CSS.

Comment: Would this work if there are images in the document or would you need to use `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: @PitaJ  yes .. as I can see Jquery tagged .. So this is a jquery solution :)

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah wait for demo please

Comment: I actually don't think this *is* a solution to his problem.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/htj8jLr7/ .. Is that what you looking for??

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the structure to get the result.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">page-header</div>
        <div class="page-content">page-content 
  <br/>
      <div id="more-cont"></div>
      <input type ="button"value="Add More Content" id="add-more">
  </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>

html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.page-header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:10px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
.page-content {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
.footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Please see the [demo](http://codepen.io/fanafazil/pen/ZbMKyY/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wcjmmcmd/)

css code:

```
 #footer {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     clear: both;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     height: 30px; 
     background: #333;
}
```

Comment: I do not want fixed. When it is fixed,if I get very long content,it is still fixed at the bottom of the screen. Not at the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by adding a `min-height` and `padding` to body and setting the footer as absolutely positioned relative to it.

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv7pwqLx/) or you can use the **Run code snippet** button to view the result.

```css
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* just for demo */

.container {
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

footer {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class='container'>
  container stuff
</div>
<footer>
  footer stuff
</footer>
</body>
```