# How to keep footer at bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

What is best practice for setting up a web page so that if there is very little content/text to be displayed on that web page the footer is displayed at the bottom of the browser window and not half way up the web page?

Comment: `position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;height:30px;`

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far ?

Comment: a good practice is to first search other similar discussions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height

Comment: I was trying to set min-height of the section :(

Comment: Top answers **did not work with REACT** -- try [this Flexbox solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382499/1873386) that works with React/Angular/html/everything, from Chris Coyier *(CSS-Tricks)*

Answer (score 95, accepted):

What you’re looking for is the *CSS Sticky Footer*.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 180px;
  /* must be same height as the footer */
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -180px;
  /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 180px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
}


/* Opera Fix thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec) */

body:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: -32767px;
  /* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: for some reason adding <!DOCTYPE html> breaks the footer.

Comment: My footer doesn't have fixed height...it may vary on different devices, or between portrait and landscape format. How to do it?

Comment: @miliu, how is your footer height calculated? If you're using relative values (like em's or vh/vw's), you can probably put in the same values here. If it's more complicated than that, CSS's [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function may come in handy.

As a last resort, consider setting the property dynamically with JavaScript using dimensions obtained e.g with [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) or jQuery.

Comment: The CSS Sticker Footer link sends me to a bunch of spam.

Comment: @Raymond26 Thanks. Removed that link.

Answer (score 41):

You could use `position:fixed;` to `bottom`.

eg:

```
#footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
```

Comment: Then it displays at the bottom of the screen no matter how much content is on the actual page. Bad advice.

Comment: @mwieczorek eh, I guess it depends on what you want? I wouldn't say Chamara's suggestion was bad. It was actually what I wanted and it worked for me :) On screen resize, my footer stays exactly where I want it to be: at the bottom of my page. Thanks Chamara.

Comment: thanks..it worked.

Comment: Nice job Chamara.  That's my jam right there.

Comment: I agree, good advice. What I wanted and thought that's what mwieczorek was asking.

Comment: ah yeah. Nice and simple. Puts it right at the bottom with no fuss. Just drop the `left:0` and it's even more straight to the point.

Comment: This works perfectly but if you then also want the main content to be scrollable if it takes up more space, you have to set the height for that programmatically and recalculate it on resize.  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  calculateMainContentHeight();
});

Comment: If the page content fits between the stuff above it and the footer, then this looks great. However, if the content is more than that, then the footer will sit **on top of** some content *(and cannot be scrolled into view)* and that is probably NOT what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page/63382499#63382499) instead.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100px;   
   background:blue;//optional
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is the best way to ensure your markup breaks on certain devices.

Answer (score 0):

set its position:fixed and bottom:0 so that it will always reside at bottom of your browser windows

Comment: Can anyone justify why this was downvoted? I guess that was the easiest way to keep the element at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Yes. It was downvoted because if a page has more content on the page, the footer still remains at the bottom of the page, no matter of the document height. This is no correct behaviour.

Comment: Radu - That's the reason for this entire discussion.  To keep the footer visible and not deep in the netherlands and the bottom of the well.

Chamara above said the same thing.  Did you downvote her too?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest is to use `position: absolute` to fix to the bottom, then a suitable margin/padding to make sure that the other text doesn't spill over the top of it.

**css:**

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

**Here is the html main content.**

```
<div class="footer"> Here is the footer. </div>
```

Comment: This works if the content does not take up the full page. It breaks once you add more content.

Comment: Downvote: As RSSM said, it breaks if the page is taller than the screen. Really, do not recommend this.

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote this code. It seemed reasonable at the time... `:)

Answer (score -5):

use this style

```
min-height:250px;
height:auto;
```