# How to keep footer at bottom of screen using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to keep footer at bottom of screen using jQuery.

I know its duplicate in css but how do it with jQuery?

I found many problem in different size of screen (small screens) or different HTML code on other solutions that use CSS.

For example this solutions use css and doesn't work for me:

[How to keep footer at bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739937/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-screen)

[CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

Please note that i have my own design code and a new style or structure can't help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in jQuery when it should be done in CSS? `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` is all you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have my own design and position fix isn't a good solution.

Comment: Then you should post a question about your specific issue as using JavaScript as a crutch for the UI is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple and easy.

Just copy/paste following code to your body before your footer or where you want to stretch.

```
<div id="js-heightControl" style="height: 0;">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#js-heightControl').css('height', $(window).height() - $('html').height() +'px');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function footerAlign() {
  $('footer').css('display', 'block');
  $('footer').css('height', 'auto');
  var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
  $('body').css('padding-bottom', footerHeight);
  $('footer').css('height', footerHeight);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  footerAlign();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  footerAlign();
});
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQxQoR

Comment: Question clearly states the need of jQuery solution. **How to keep footer at bottom of screen using jQuery**

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check and let me know if that works.

Comment: It doesn't need to write too many code, The answer is simple.

Comment: Yes, I found this answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks for this! but my footer is a bit tall how to adjust it to your desired height?