# Blank space at the bottom

Tags: css, footer, space

I'm working on the website http://pcagrade.fr/8-certification-cartes-pokemon.html and I have a CSS issue: when I zoom out with my desktop browser, my footer don't follow the bottom of my browser and then I have a big blank space under (comes from my body tag). How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You can find this solution by searching for "sticky footer" or "fixed footer" either here on SO or on Google.

Answer (score 1):

use beloved css part

```
#footer{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work good : my content is hidden by the footer now if I don't have zoom

Comment: I think you have to check your html layout,
check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739937/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-screen