# Issue with footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a problem with the footer in HTML and CSS.
I want to put it down using :

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;`
```

It puts it down but If the page has a scroll, it does not drop it to the end.

Comment: add a dummy div at the end of your page, with the same height as your footer.

Comment: This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739937/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-screen Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS property in place of `absolute`

`position: fixed;`

Comment: This is good solution and I now use it. But I need to put a footer to down of page.

Comment: put bottom value equal to the height of the footer. Or you can use 'margin-bottom' property on which you have put position fixed. the value of  'margin-bottom' equal to the height of the footer.

Comment: Please send the code via codepen or any other source. So, That I can debug.