# Set Footer Section at the bottom , VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have installed vue cli & added header & footer components in a vue page but they are coming one under another how i can place footer section in bottom ?

Here is the code pen - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-colden-ql4qe?file=/src/App.vue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPSI7.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep footer at bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739937/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-screen)

Comment: I am trying that answer

Comment: No that answer didn't help

Comment: Worked fine for me. Just needed to remove extra margin

Comment: Have you tried in the codepen - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-colden-ql4qe?file=/src/App.vue  ?

Comment: Yes, I did that already

Comment: Can you please advise what is preventing it (footer) from placing it in bottom ( which class' css ) ? That would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it using position:fixed; to bottom.

```
#footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: exactly, it is just CSS stuff, no related to vue nor vue-component https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fog-dezz4?file=/src/components/Footer.vue

Comment: This will make it sit at the bottom of the page, but when the content fills the page there will be overlapping as it will be FIXED to the bottom of the viewable page, not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also:
in App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app" :theme="getTheme">
    <AppHeader/>
    <v-main>      
      <router-view/>      
    </v-main>
    <AppFooter/>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
    min-height: 100vh; 
    margin: 0; 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}
</style>
```

And in AppFooter:

```
<template>
    <footer class="footer">
...
    </footer>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    height: auto;
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use position: static, such that the element follows the natural order of components and divs. It will naturally fall to the bottom. Only way I could get it to work. In tailwind it is just class="static".