# Flushing footer to bottom of the page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I know that there are many topics about this question but i can't get it to work. I'd like my footer to be flushed to the bottom of the page (not fixed). Could somebody tell me how to do this in Bootstrap?

This is the structure of my page

```
<body>

    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- some code -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
             Copyright &copy; 2015. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: One way is to use the `min-height` for the content!

Comment: What have you tried? There's no way none of the current solutions don't work.

Comment: Hope this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324395/bootstrap-3-flush-footer-to-bottom-not-fixed

Comment: Can you clarify? I assume you want it at the bottom of the window unless the content is taller than the window?

Comment: Can you provide us with CSS you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that bootstrap would do it:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/