# How to use bootstrap to create a footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create a bootstrap footer using the class navbar-fixed-bottom, however I do not want this to be a fixed element and I want to have to scroll to it.
This is my existing code
Any help?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left"><strong>Click08.co.uk</strong> is a <strong>Web Daddy</strong> project.</p>
            <a class="navbar-btn btn btn-success pull-right" href="../Home.php">Return To Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to have a scroll to it?

Comment: So rather than it being always visible at the bottom of the screen, the content will be there and as you scroll to the bottom it will then appear

Comment: Similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324395/bootstrap-3-flush-footer-to-bottom-not-fixed

Comment: I see what you mean. Why not use the `footer` class? @L.Smith

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/9m348k3L/