# Force Bootstrap's variable height footer to the bottom of page or content, whichever is lower

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

In my bootstrap page, I want to force the `<footer>...</footer>` to be at the bottom of the page or the content, whichever is lower.

And there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864663/9382) for that already which works great.  However, that approach requires that I know ahead of time what the height of the footer will be.

How do I achieve the same thing, but the footer height is determined by its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to achieve sticky footer.

Using `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `section` will make it `flexible`, it will acquire all available free space in [flex-container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Flexible_Boxes_Vocabulary).

> [`flex: <positive-number>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)
>
> Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.Equivalent to flex: 1 0.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 1px; /* Height hack for IE */
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* This will make section flexible */
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<section></section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Last I checked Flexbox didn't work well with Bootstrap.  Did that change?

Comment: `flexbox` is grid system, it will work with bootstrap too, I have used it a lot, especially for `sticky footer` or `sticky sidebar`. `bootstrap4` is using `flexbox`.