# Put footer at buttom without hiding page content when resizing

Tags: css

I want the footer to be stuck at the buttom of the page, the I added: `buttom:0px;` and made it `position:fixed;`, but then when I resize window the footer hides other stuff (I want it stay at bottom):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BigcC.png)

I also tried with `position:static;` but then it changes the selected height:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJXhT.png)

here code:

```
footer {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: gray;
    border-top: 1px solid #2672fb;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
   position:static;
}
<body>
<div>
...
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 Flush footer to bottom. not fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324395/bootstrap-3-flush-footer-to-bottom-not-fixed)

Comment: @Porky answered you question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a wrapping element that held everything except the footer. It had a negative margin equal to the height of the footer.
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;


  /* Equal to height of footer */
  /* But also accounting for potential margin-bottom of last child */
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.footer,
.push {
   width:100%;
   height:100px;
}
.footer{
background-color:yellow;}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <button id="add">Add Data</button>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="push"> 
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>    
    </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: The question has not a `jQuery` label

Comment: I just use jquery for addition of content

Comment: Edited can you please take back your down vote if you down voted on my question