# How to hide and show a table-row (css-tables)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide and show a table row using css-tables and pure JavaScript (No jQuery).

I've got a `div` with the `display` set to `table-row` and a `nav` inside of it. No matter what I do, `border-collapse` etc, the `div` still maintains some of it's height.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
  <!-- Header -->
  <header id='header'> <!-- Table Row 1 -->
    <div id="header-table">
      <div id='back'>
        <button id='back-button'>&#8592;</button>
      </div>
      <div id="title">
        <h1 id='title-h1'>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <button id='menu-button'>&equiv;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

    <nav id="menu-nav">
      <a href="#intro">Introductory Page</a>
      <a href="#list">Activity List</a>
      <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </nav>

  <div id="body"> <!-- Table Row 3 -->

    <div id="wrapper">
```

CSS

```
header#header {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
}

div#menu-nav-cell {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

nav#menu-nav {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0em;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  background: pink;
}


div#body {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

div#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using `display: none`?

Maybe I misunderstood, since you said you have a `div` with a `nav` inside, but I cannot see that in your html sample.

I think you want to show/hide the navigation. This can be done by adding this css rule:

```
nav#menu-nav.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and javascript

```
document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("menu-nav").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3oounq/1/)**

---

If you want to animate the height, you can do this:

```
/* new rules that I added */
nav#menu-nav {
  line-height: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: line-height .2s, background-color .2s;
}

nav#menu-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: height .2s;
}

nav#menu-nav.hidden {
    line-height: 0em;
    background-color: transparent;
}
nav#menu-nav.hidden a {
    height: 0;
}
```

The trick is to use `overflow: hidden; display:inline-block` for the table cells, instead of `display:table-cell`.
This way, changing the height and line-height to zero works fine.

However there is still some height (around 3px) still visible, so I decided to animate the background-color to transparent as well. If you comment that part that animates the background color, you will understand what I mean.

**[jsFiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3oounq/3/)**

Comment: display none works, but cannot be animated with css transition.