# Footer to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I would like to create a footer that is at the bottom of the page, both in the case of little content and in case there is very little.

I have already followed several tutorials but either do not work or do not give the desired result, maybe I've tried something wrong.

Anyone can help me? Thank you

EDIT: here it's my code

HTML of page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test Pagina Vuota Footer
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, .container {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
            }
            .container {
                padding-top: 97px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="/inc/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/inc/sticky-footer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <? include("./inc/navbar"); ?>

            <div class="content">
                content of page
            </div>


        <?php include("./inc/footer"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML of footer

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            /inc/footer
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Footer del sito">
        <style type="text/css">
            .footer {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: orange;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="/inc/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/inc/footer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="footer">
            &copy; ************.altervista.org 2017
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
// Window load event used just in case window height is dependant upon images
$(window).bind("load", function() { 

       var footerHeight = 0,
           footerTop = 0,
           $footer = $("#footer");

       positionFooter();

       function positionFooter() {

                footerHeight = $footer.height();
                footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";

               if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: footerTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }

       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionFooter)
               .resize(positionFooter)

});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: You need to show us some code. And do you mean you want it to be on the bottom of the page (sticky), or always visible at the bottom of the viewport regardless how far you're scrolled (fixed)?

Comment: Please post the code, where you're having trouble

Comment: I want sticky footer

Comment: Do you want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/643879/2563833

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: @DanielBeck I've already tried but did not go right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most `flex`ible way is probably to use `display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 100vh;` on `.container`, and set `margin-top: auto` on `.footer` so it will push itself to the end of the flex parent's main axis.

You should also remove all of the `<html><body>` structural stuff from your footer include, especially bundling scripts that you've already included on the page, like jquery. You only need the elements for the footer itself.

```css
html, body, .container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  padding-top: 97px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <nav>nav</nav>

  <div class="content">
    content of page
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    &copy; ************.altervista.org 2017
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: So in the files included on the page I just have to put the footer code without creating a real page that is included?

Comment: @Takabrycheri right. You only need `<html><body><title><head>` on the page once. Your include files should just be the html for the footer code. No need to nest `<html><body>`, etc in a page that already has `<html><body>`, etc. And if that JS you're including is to create the sticky footer, I don't think you need it if my CSS solution works for you. You're also missing `<!doctype html>` on your main html. It should be the first line of the document (above `<html>`)

Comment: Oh ok, I thought I had to put <! Doctype html> only in HTML files, while this being PHP I did not know had to be put.

Comment: Now I try it :)

Comment: @Takabrycheri your PHP is simply outputting HTML to the browser, so you need to add the doctype because the browser doesn't see any of your PHP - it only sees the HTML document the PHP is spitting out. And HTML documents require the doctype.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many many ways to do this. One easy way is to make sure the content above the footer has a minimum height of the whole screen minus the height of the footer.

```
<div id="content" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);"> 
    Your content goes here.
</div>
<div id="footer" style="height: 50px"> 
    Your footer goes here.
</div>
```