# Sticky footer in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to add footer in react which is tuck to the bottom of the page(not position: fixed ) when content is more I should see footer after scrolling till end and if content is less then it should display at the bottom. How to do it in React.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by making your footer a component and giving it the class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS do the trick with the power of `flexbox` and `min-height`.
Basically, a `.wrapper` for your container having minimum height of 100% of the vertical height, ie: `100vh`, then the children `components` or `elements` (eg. `.navbar`, `.content` and `.footer`) sharing the height, you can make the `.content` assume the remaining height of the `.wrapper` while the other components assume the size of themselves, see below snippet for solution.

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
/* You can ignore the styling below */
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.footer, .navbar, .content {
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Landing Page Flexbox Layout With Navbar Full Height Content And Footer Sticky To The Bottom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
        Navbar
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Content</h1>
          <h2>Takes remaining height and grows if needed!</h2>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
        Footer
        </footer>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can read more about flexbox here: [W3schools CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

You can also play around with this sandbox I created for ReactJS applying the above styles: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-landing-page-flexbox-layout-with-navbar-full-height-of-content-and-footer-sticky-to-bottom-x3tj6?file=/src/App.js:66-411)

Answer (score -3):

The behaviour you need looks exactly like the sticky position in css.I recommend using pure css here:

```
footer{
    position: sticky;
}
```

See more [here](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

Comment: `position: sticky`will keep the footer visible all the time, that'Äs not what Ark tried to achieve