# Align the footer at the bottom with variable content height

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to achieve this: [image]

I know this looks like an already asked question but I have tried all the available solutions of stackoverflow.

My current structure is:
HTML:

```
<div class='app'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.app{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1a1f25;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    top: 0;
}
.footer{
    color: lightgray;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: black;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Update: I tried checking the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b), but my website is responsive and that answer is for those footers which have fixed height. Which makes it difficult to convert that solution for my usecase.

Comment: I tried that also but that didn't work for me.

Comment: your CSS is correct but your implementation is incorrect.

Comment: take the footer div outside of app div. then it will work.

Comment: app div is like application wrapper and changing that will change a lot. Can't even take things out of that. Any other way?, thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: add static height to your app. or use javascript code to get the height and assign it to the app div

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the response I took the footer out of the App container and then assigned it a static height.