# Keep footer at down of page (but when it is not hiding elements)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress `sparkling` theme from `Colorlib`. Demo of this theme is here: https://colorlib.com/sparkling/ 
If you will delete part of content you will reproduce this issue - the footer will go up.

What i see is situation that there is space after footer:
[image]

I read about my problem here: [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b)

But:

1) I do not want to see this footer always. I want it to be at bottom.

2) I want it to be full responsive - size is dynamic (RWD) i am not sure what is the size of the footer.

What i tried:

```
#footer-area {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    z-index: 100;
}
```

It's kinda ok - but i do not want to see the footer always. **It should not cover anything behind it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this CSS help you.

Please try below CSS.

```
  html,body,#page{
    min-height: 100vh;
   }

  #page{
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
   -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content{
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox. and give `flex-grow` property to the main content.

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction : column;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
}
div {
  flex: 1; /* or flex-grow: 1  */;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: gold;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  div {
    flex:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    header: sized to content
    <br>(but is it really?)
</header>
<div>
    main content: fills remaining space<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
</div>
<footer>
    footer: content
</footer>
```

Comment: The example you provided is not good cause it hides content on smaller devices and it shows footer always: https://imgur.com/a/puKRE3l

Comment: you can use a media query to achieve it. `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* style */ }`

Comment: Not sure what you mean if you could please update your answer and example.

Comment: It still does not work as it supposed to, see: https://imgur.com/a/WUEvoD2
Footer is hiding content. As i mentioned in the question - this is dynamic matter (RWD) and you are using fixed size here. See the accepted answer - it works fine.

Comment: No, it does not - try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position: absolute;`

```css
header{
  background-color:red;
}
footer{
  background-color:green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: This won't work - cause on smaller devices the footer will hide the content behind it.

Comment: @tryingHard  check that link https://jsfiddle.net/ndtfw5us/4/. hope this will be helpful for you