# When I position my footer to the bottom of the page it postions in the middle of the page

Tags: css

When I position my footer to the bottom of the page it postions in the middle of the page

When is set the element to position absolute and the bottom attribute equal to zero it show up in the middle of the whole page instead of the bottom. Is this because my page is bigger than one screen and if so how do I solve this?

```
#footer{
height: 24.72vh;
background-color: aqua;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

}

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Code or URL, please.

Answer (score 0):

the parent of element of your footer must have `height:100%;` and `position:relative;`

and footer should be last element.

OR

position:fixed, instead of position:absolute

**some reference links:**

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/

https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

[CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b)