# Footer is not fixed at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The footer is not fixed at the bottom when the contents of the page are less than the window height. Below is the screenshot..

contents more than window size:[image]

contents less than window height:

[image]

HTML :

```
<footer class="page-footer text-center font-small mt-4 wow fadeIn">


        <div class="pt-4">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-white" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/getting-started/download/" target="_blank"
            role="button">Download MDB
            <i class="fas fa-download ml-2"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-white" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/" target="_blank" role="button">Start
            free tutorial
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart ml-2"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--/.Call to action-->

        <hr class="my-4">

        <div class="footer-copyright py-3">
          © 2019 Copyright:
          <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/" target="_blank"> MDBootstrap.com </a>
        </div>
        <!--/.Copyright-->

      </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
 min-height: 100vh; /* will cover the 100% of viewport */
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 100px; /* height of your footer */
}
footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you link some code?

Comment: @AndersSørensen No, at SO we don't want _"linked code"_ ... please read [mcve], which says a verifiable sample **within** the question itself

Comment: I'm building a website using django and bootstrap. I have limited knowledge in HTML and CSS. I will post the CSS which effects the view when i do some changes.

Comment: @LGSon, …Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself
…Reproducible – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem.   Anders asked code for the 1&2 points mentioned in the example you sent. So what was the necessity of you saying No?

Comment: Is you're footer start tag missing from you copying?

Comment: @LGSon,I do follow the guidelines. But as mentioned in the doc, those three are the points to be followed when a code is posted." No, at SO we don't want "linked code" this was an irrelevant comment. I cannot post the whole CSS code since it has hundreds of lines for footer and i couldn't differentiate btn them as i'm a beginner in FE.Hope you understand!

Comment: @anders, Yes. i will update now

Comment: try with clear:both; on footer

Comment: @LGSon, Since this might be the day to day issue faced by FE devs and i was expecting some hints regarding what was going wrong, i didn't post the code. Lets wind up this argument here. Cheers!!

Comment: @Anders, It didn't work

Comment: I understand LGSon. It is just a point of view conflict. Still trying on the issue, nothing seems to help.

Comment: You need position:relative aswell and set margin top negative. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/689290/4548398

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b)

Answer (score 0):

strong text

just add fixed-bottom in footer class

footer class="page-footer text-center font-small mt-4 wow fadeIn fixed-bottom"

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

This solved my issue. Now footer is fixed at the bottom regardless of the content and window size.

```
<footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;" class="page-footer text-center font-small mt-4 wow fadeIn  ">
```