# Position an element at bottom of the visible space while scrolling on Android mobile Firefox

Tags: html, css, mobile

I want to put a footer at the bottom of the page, which has quite large amount of data, but the footer should be over the content at the top layer:

```
<html><head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">                         
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    height:2000px;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
  .main{
    height: 800px;
    width:20%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:red;
  }
  .bottom{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color:green;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">main content
    <br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</body></html>
```

Now my problem is, that if I scroll the page, the bottom keeps on its position where it was generated.

I tried `position:fixed`, which is fine on desktop Firefox, but not on mobile Firefox: https://spacetrace.org/test.html

If you resize the screen with two fingers, you get the bottom displaced.

How do I keep it at the bottom with only CSS on Firefox mobile too?

Comment: Hey rubo, do you want to stick it at the bottom of your main div or the bottom of your body ??

Comment: The bottom of the visible screen

Comment: It should float over whatever is under it at any screen size

Comment: https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/VwjeJWw try this

Comment: This is not working. The green bottom is not visible until you scroll down. It should be visible all the time

Comment: Ah alright now i get what you want to do is to use JavaScript in order to read the view window x and y and adjust the position of the bottom div based on that I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">                         
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin:0px; 
  }
  .main {
    width:20%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 18px; /* height of the fixed div at bottom */
    background-color:red;
  }
  .bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color:green;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">main content
    <br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>  
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` element has has the `position` property set to `absolute`, which gives it a `margin` of `8px`. This gives the page a trailing space, along with the fact that the body has a fixed `height`, which the footer itself tries to stick to.

**Solution:** Remove all of the CSS from the `body` element, it's unnecessary and a bad practice. If your page is too short, give it a `min-height` property of `100%`.

Comment: I tried to remove the height from body in my game https://spacetrace.org but the bottom messages bar keeps jumping down to about 2000px after a second

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i didnt use javascript and i think it will work fine using this css code:

```
    <html><head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">                         
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
  }
  .main{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-height:100%;
    height: 800px;
    width:20%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:red;
  }
  .bottom{
    z-index:1;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:green;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">main content
    <br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</body></html>
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/VwjeJWw