# How can i move the footer to the bottom?

Tags: css, sass

Can someone help me how can I move my footer to the bottom using position: relative?

[FOOTER PROBLEM PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpWiA.jpg)

```
#page-footer {
    .list-inline {
        display: none;
    }
}
.s-footer {
    background-color: $primary;
    margin-top: auto!important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid $primary;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: $default;
    .tool_dataprivacy {
        display: none;
    }
    .helplink {
        display: none;
    }
}
.c-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

This is the code from the theme, i haven't made any changes from that code. Thank you!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20352949/5566935) will help you I believe. I would prefer thre `flexbox` one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set min-height to container

```
.c-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important;
    min-height: 80vh; //adjust this accordingly
}
```

Or make the footer fixed

```
.s-footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
```