# Email Footer always at the bottom

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I found this question: [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b)

But this doesn't solve my problem, because the stone age email clients don't support all of this *wizardy*.

What is a good way supported cross most (or better all) email clients that pushes the footer to the bottom of the screen if the content isn't long enough?
When I set a `min-height` on the content the footer will sometimes outside of the screen and above is just a lot of whitespace.
`position` isn't an option here because thats [not really supported](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-position/) and I don't want the footer to overlap my content.

Currently my footer has no fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't. Website techniques require a calculation of the screen height, completed by the CSS method you're using and then distributing that dimension to the main content to allow the footer to sit perfectly at the bottom.

These techniques won't work in all email clients for all of the different screen sizes.

If your content is too short to reach the bottom of a phone screen, that's a bigger concern. I don't understand a full template build for a short message.
And setting a height on your content or padding the sections out enough so your footer is a little lower shouldn't be an issue in this day and age.

The fold is so over hyped.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I thought the same that it's not possible, just wanted to be sure.
The email is for an onlineshop and some small messages like "password reset" don't have that much content. Just out of interest, what do you mean with "the fold is over hyped" I don't get the reference, sorry

Comment: @skarpeta - Oh, it was just a joke about designers and marketers being obsessed with trying to cram the most important content at the top of your emails & websites. That way end users don't have to scroll for your promotion etc. It used to be a massive thing to design & build for 'above the fold' but has died out.