# Push footer to the bottom of a short page

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to push the footer to the bottom of the page and since the page doesn't have much content the footer floats up and doesn't move to the bottom.

I tried positioning my footer as a fixed element as a workaround and it works but it doesn't in this condition:

[image]

In this dimension the footer behaves like you see and it is perfectly expected, hence showing a loophole in my workaround.

This is the website's address: https://n-ii-ma.github.io/Portfolio-Website/contact.html

These are the codes for that part:

```css
/* Contact Footer */

.contact-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="main-title">Nima's Portfolio</h1>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./index.html#projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./contact.html">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="contact-section">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      <p>Use the links below to contact me and I'll reach out to you as soon as possible</p>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="https://github.com/n-ii-ma" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope-square fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="contact-footer">&copy; All Rights Reserved</footer>
</body>
```

Is there a way for my footer to always stay at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Question is unclear hence the footer is already fixed at the bottom, could you explain more what are you trying to implement here?

Comment: @TariqSaeed I updated the question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I've seen the example link you left, but it is indeed at the bottom of the page. Do you want it to stay at the bottom of the white div, instead of the bottom of the whole page?

Comment: Caio I guess he not want it to be layerwise over the other elements. he want to only push it at the bottom if the page content is to less to keep the footer at the bottom of the viewport when no scroll is present.

Comment: @tacoshy Yes that's exactly what I wanted and your solution totally fixed my problem. Thanks a billion times!

Comment: Can you please check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67846892/9339254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution that is fully supported is to use Flexbox.

1. We give the body a `min-height: 100vh` so it spans at least the entire viewports height.
2. The default margin of the body will make the page overflow by default. To counter that, we need to reset the margin with: `margin: 0`
3. We re-add a padding. The default margin of most browsers is 8px. SO I chose that. You can take what ever you like.
4. The padding will also cause an overflow because of the box-modell. To counter that we use: `box-sizing: border-box`
5. Then we use flexbox: `display: flex`.
6. To maintain the normal block-level behavior we use: `flex-direction: column`
7. To push the footer at the bottom we use: `margin-top: auto;`. That will push the footer to the bottom of the page if the page content is less then the viewport height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="main-title">Nima's Portfolio</h1>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./index.html#projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./contact.html">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="contact-section">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      <p>Use the links below to contact me and I'll reach out to you as soon as possible</p>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="https://github.com/n-ii-ma" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope-square fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="contact-footer">&copy; All Rights Reserved</footer>
</body>
```