# How do I put one div to be a footer inside of a bigger main div?

Tags: html, css

I want simple header -> content -> footer sections in my div.
What I want to achieve is this: [image: code example]

And this is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2m816kq/).

I don't get it very well this relative layout which I tried to use for my footer. Relative layout should be looking for its parent element (in this case `class="main"` and based on main class to adjust `bottom:0` to its bottom border of main class, however, it doesn't work in that way.)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20352949/16688813).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Flex

```
.procedure-box {
        border: 1px solid #ada9a9;
        /* display: inline-block;*/ /*Remove this*/
        display:flex; /*Add This*/
        flex-direction:column; /*Add this*/
        height: 350px;
        width: 300px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        justify-content:space-between; /*Update this*/
    }
    .header {
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    .content-body {
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        flex:1;  /*Add this*/
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/h3fm9nt0/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/h3fm9nt0/3/ Updated answer

Comment: can you please update your answer in case if no `<p>` element between header and footer. Now it's a case that button goes up, if I delete `<p>` section entirely. Thanks

Comment: update my answer check now.