# How do I put my footer in the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the flex layout exercise from The Odin Project.

[Here is what my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ghCK.png) but I can't figure out how to make the footer stick at the bottom of the page so that the main container can occupy most of the screen. For the exercise, I can only use display: flex and its properties. What is wrong with my code?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,900;1,900&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FEF9F8;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    
}

header {
    background-color: #ED9275;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 32px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 16px;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #2A6877;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 16px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
}

.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 16px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #ED9275;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 72px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Box Zilla</h1>
    </header>

<main>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Packages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
               <h2>Heading 1</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 6</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        <footer>
            <p>Property of Box Zilla Corporated</p>
            
        </footer>

    
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into CSS positions - this will help you decipher what you need

Comment: Answers on this link may help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to add `position: relative;` with `bottom: 0;` on your `footer`. However, when your content does not exceed the length of the page (y-axis scroll) the `footer` will be directly under the content and not at the very bottom of the page.

In the event that there is no scroll and you still want the `footer` at the bottom I would then use either position `fixed` or `absolute` and add `width: 100%;` on the `footer.`

I added a static height on your `main-container` to demonstrate how `relative` works.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,900;1,900&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FEF9F8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #ED9275;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 32px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1074px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #2A6877;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 16px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 16px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #ED9275;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Box Zilla</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Packages</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 1</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 3</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 4</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 5</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Heading 6</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Property of Box Zilla Corporated</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your webpage has 3 main elements

1. Header
2. Content
3. Footer

I would suggest you to add `justify-content:space-between;` to the body tag as you have to use flex properties

*Alternatively*, you can use a media query to keep footer at bottom using position. After that, your content will fill the page's empty space and your footer will be automatically at the bottom

**Changes Made**

- Moved footer outside `main` tag (idk why)

**Tips**

- Use padding in percentage (ex: `Padding:2%;`) for responsiveness

Have a nice day ^_^

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,900;1,900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FEF9F8;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;

    /* Changes Made */
    justify-content: space-between;

    
}

header {
    background-color: #ED9275;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 32px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 16px;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #2A6877;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 16px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
}

.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 16px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #ED9275;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 72px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Box Zilla</h1>
    </header>

<main>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Packages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
               <h2>Heading 1</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
             <div class="card">
                <h2>Heading 6</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, quaerat?</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


      

    
</main>

<footer>
    <p>Property of Box Zilla Corporated</p>
    
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```