# footer doesn't fix to bottom of a page when scrolling with not much content on page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, responsive

my footer is lifting off the bottom of the page when there is not a lot of content to scroll through
[image]

in the bottom of the picture ie:
privacy policy/terms and conditions is a footer in the parent app.
The footer i'm concerned with on the mfe which is highlighted is fixed to the bottom of the page while scrolling until it reaches the very bottom it should sit above the parent app footer, which it is doing when there is a lot of content on the page, but when there isn't much content on the page it has this space underneath it?

Comment: Please provide the html and css you have tried in the question

Answer (score 0):

Provide your HTML and CSS code also or you can check out this thread also: [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b?rq=2)