# Footer not stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Why it not working? I want the footer to stay at the bottom all the time I don't want him to move
I don't now how to change it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #b4b9d1;
  background-image: url(Photos/New.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.myfooter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.myfooter p {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Photos/hty.png" style="height: 54.5px; width: 88.75px" alt="my Logo">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation-items">
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
</main>
<div class="myfooter">
  <p>this is the footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just checked here and it's working fine for me. Could you please share more details about the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/7hpf2649/

Comment: I pasted your code into a snippet and it appears to work. Provide a [mcve] please

Comment: If you meant a sticky footer (bottom of the page, irrespective of content height), you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20352949/11597845)

Comment: Footer is at the bottom, what you are trying to achieve please explain clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.