# Why is does my footer stuck in the middle of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I tried everything but my footer is stuck in the middle, I even set the body height to 100%/100vh.
footer in the middle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzp2i.png)
css:

```
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
font-family: "Righteous", sans-serif;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
color: #536976 !important;
}
.d-flex {
width: 100%;
}
.footer {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
margin-top: auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
.footer p {
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
}
.padding {
padding-top: 20px;
}

.form-hide {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.delete-btn {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.panel-body {
padding: 15px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
}
.inline {
display: inline;
}

.compose {
margin-top: 50px;
height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
.post {
margin-top: 50px;
}
.content {
display: -webkit-box;
\-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
\-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
}
.journee {
background: #536976;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #484e76, #536976);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #484e76, #536976);
\-webkit-background-clip: text;
\-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

footer:

`<footer class="bg-body-tertiary text-center text-lg-start">     <!-- Copyright -->     <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: #000">     © 2020 Copyright:     <a class="text-body" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>     </div>     <!-- Copyright --> </footer>`

I tried to keep it fixed with `position: fixed`.
also the footer is stuck under the posts
i dont know whats happening
i am using bootstrap 5

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: This question has several solutions: [stackoverflow.com/questions/643879](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is based on this question: [questions/643879](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879).

This allows to keep the `<header>` and `<footer>` dynamic.

This code will put the footer at the bottom of the page,
In case there is no content to fill the entire page, the footer will be at the bottom of the screen.

```css
body { 
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  background:#49515a;
  color: white;
  
  /* use flex */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column; 
}

header, footer {
  min-height:50px; 
  background:black; 
}

.content {
  /* between header and footer */
  flex:1; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh; /* Set minimum height to 100% of the viewport height */
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Righteous", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer p {
  margin-top: 5px; /* Adjust as needed */
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

body takes at least 100% of the viewport height. with margin-top: auto on the .footer it'll be pushed to the bottom of the flex container.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you're using Flexbox properly.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-family: "Righteous", sans-serif;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Use min-height for full viewport height */
}

.content {
    flex: 1; /* Take up the remaining space */
}
```

some extra CSS:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```